# How to fix Array indexOf() in JavaScript for Internet Explorer browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

If you have worked with JavaScript at any length you are aware that Internet Explorer does not implement the ECMAScript function for Array.prototype.indexOf() [including Internet Explorer 8]. It is not a huge problem, because you can extend the functionality on your page with the following code.

```
Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
     for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
         if (this[i] === obj) { return i; }
     }
     return -1;
}
```

When should I implement this?

Should I wrap it on all my pages with the following check, which checks if the prototype function exists and if not, go ahead and extend the Array prototype?

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {

    // Implement function here

}
```

Or do browser check and if it is Internet Explorer then just implement it?

```
//Pseudo-code

if (browser == IE Style Browser) {

     // Implement function here

}
```

Comment: Actually `Array.prototype.indexOf` is not part of ECMA-262/ECMAScript. See http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf Maybe you're thinking `String.prototype.indexOf`...

Comment: It's an extension, not part of the original standard.  It should, however, be implemented as part of Javascript 1.6 (which IE fails to do) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.6

Comment: @Josh: was just referring to "IE does not implement the ECMAScript function..."

Comment: Your implementation of `Array.indexOf` doesn't take negative starting indices into account. See Mozilla's suggestion stop-gap implementation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: I've updated the question to use "===", because I'm worried people will copy it with the "==" and that would be wrong - other than that it's fine. See Eli Grey's answer.

Comment: Actually, Array.prototype.indexOf is a part of ECMAScript 5 (where the link to the standard now goes): "15.4.4.14 Array.prototype.indexOf ( searchElement [ , fromIndex ] )"

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Do it like this...

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {

}
```

As [recommended compatibility by MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/IndexOf).

In general, browser detection code is a big no-no.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to edit the question but feel free to remove the ECMAScript lingo and replace with the appropriate wording. Thanks Again

Comment: Be careful if you use this kind of detection. Another library might implement this function before you test it, and it might not be standards compliant (prototype has done it a while ago). If I were working in a hostile environment (lots of other coders using lots of distinct libraries), I wouldn't trust any of these...

Comment: The "Linked" column ---> is really handy! I love the answer here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-internet-explorer-browsers?lq=1

Comment: Does it has to be wrapped in every js file?

Comment: Who is MDC exactly?

Answer (score 142):

Alternatively, you could use the [jQuery 1.2 inArray function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/), which should work across browsers:

```
jQuery.inArray( value, array [, fromIndex ] )
```

Comment: The 'indexOf' is native code (right), so will the jQuery 'inArray()' be as fast, such as use native when available and poly-fill when not?

Comment: Ok so to answer my own comment (above), I just implemented it and on Chrome it's as fast as when I was using 'indexOf()', but in IE 8 it is very, very slow... so at least we know that 'inArray()' uses native when it can.

Answer (score 79):

The full code then would be this:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
         for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
             if (this[i] === obj) { return i; }
         }
         return -1;
    }
}
```

For a really thorough answer and code to this as well as other array functions check out Stack Overflow question *[Fixing JavaScript Array functions in Internet Explorer (indexOf, forEach, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790001)*.

Comment: thank you for just having the full thing. I visit this page frequently whenever I need cross-platform indexOf in a new project, and your snippet is the only one with full code. :) Those few seconds really add up when one frequents this page.

Answer (score 16):

The underscore.js library has an [indexOf](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#indexOf) function you can use instead:

```
_.indexOf([1, 2, 3], 2)
```

Comment: This answer avoids [messing with the array prototype](http://stackoverflow.com/q/780422/425313), and it delegates to the native indexOf when available.  I like it.

Comment: Seems to be the easiest way if you are able to include underscore or lodash

Answer (score 10):

You should check if it's not defined using `if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)`.

Also, your implementation of `indexOf` is not correct. You must use `===` instead of `==` in your `if (this[i] == obj)` statement, otherwise `[4,"5"].indexOf(5)` would be 1 according to your implementation, which is incorrect.

I recommend you use [the implementation on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/IndexOf#Compatibility).

Answer (score 9):

There is Mozilla official solution:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

```
(function() {
    /**Array*/
    // Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.14
    // Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.14
    if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
        Array.prototype.indexOf = function(searchElement, fromIndex) {
            var k;
            // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing
            //    the this value as the argument.
            if (null === this || undefined === this) {
                throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
            }
            var O = Object(this);
            // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get
            //    internal method of O with the argument "length".
            // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
            var len = O.length >>> 0;
            // 4. If len is 0, return -1.
            if (len === 0) {
                return -1;
            }
            // 5. If argument fromIndex was passed let n be
            //    ToInteger(fromIndex); else let n be 0.
            var n = +fromIndex || 0;
            if (Math.abs(n) === Infinity) {
                n = 0;
            }
            // 6. If n >= len, return -1.
            if (n >= len) {
                return -1;
            }
            // 7. If n >= 0, then Let k be n.
            // 8. Else, n<0, Let k be len - abs(n).
            //    If k is less than 0, then let k be 0.
            k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);
            // 9. Repeat, while k < len
            while (k < len) {
                // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
                //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
                // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the
                //    HasProperty internal method of O with argument Pk.
                //   This step can be combined with c
                // c. If kPresent is true, then
                //    i.  Let elementK be the result of calling the Get
                //        internal method of O with the argument ToString(k).
                //   ii.  Let same be the result of applying the
                //        Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm to
                //        searchElement and elementK.
                //  iii.  If same is true, return k.
                if (k in O && O[k] === searchElement) {
                    return k;
                }
                k++;
            }
            return -1;
        };
    }
})();
```

Comment: Just being pedantic but MDN is not just Mozilla. It is a community driven project that contains Mozilla staff but also volunteers, anyone can join and contribute.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend this to anyone looking for missing functionality:

http://code.google.com/p/ddr-ecma5/

It brings in most of the missing ecma5 functionality to older browers :)

Comment: ** Although I will note that I have had problems in IE7 with this lib.

Answer (score 2):

This was my implementation. Essentially, add this before any other scripts on the page. i.e. in your master for a global solution for Internet Explorer 8. I also added in the trim function which seems to be used in allot of frameworks.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script>
    if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
        Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
            for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
                if (this[i] === obj) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        };
    }

    if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
        String.prototype.trim = function() {
            return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        };
    };
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

it works for me.

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/) {
    var len = this.length >>> 0;

    var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
    from = (from < 0)? Math.ceil(from) : Math.floor(from);
    if (from < 0)
    from += len;

    for (; from < len; from++) {
      if (from in this && this[from] === elt)
        return from;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the Underscore.js

`var arr=['a','a1','b'] 
_.filter(arr, function(a){ return a.indexOf('a') > -1; })`