# jquery save json data object in cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

How do I save JSON data in a cookie?

My JSON data looks like this

```
$("#ArticlesHolder").data('15', {name:'testname', nr:'4',price:'400'});
$("#ArticlesHolder").data('25', {name:'name2', nr:'1', price:'100'});
$("#ArticlesHolder").data('37', {name:'name3', nr:'14', price:'60'});
```

And I want to do something like

```
var dataStore = $.cookie("basket-data", $("#ArticlesHolder").data());
```

and to retrieve the data i want to load it into `$("#ArticlesHolder")` like

```
$.each($.cookie("basket-data"), function(i,e){
 $("#ArticlesHolder").data(i, e);
});
```

does anyone know if I'm on the right track or should this be done in some other way? Simply put, how do i put and pull json data from a cookie?

Comment: Just being pedantic, but there's no "JSON data" in your question. You have some JavaScript objects you've defined via object literal notation (not JSON, JSON is a subset of object literal notation), but there is no JSON there. http://json.org You almost certainly want to *use* JSON as the data format for storing your objects in the cookie string, though.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

You can serialize the data as JSON, like this:

```
$.cookie("basket-data", JSON.stringify($("#ArticlesHolder").data()));
```

Then to get it from the cookie:

```
$("#ArticlesHolder").data(JSON.parse($.cookie("basket-data")));
```

This relies on [`JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/json#Using_native_JSON) to serialize/deserialize your data object, for older browsers (IE<8) include [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) to get the `JSON` functionality. This example uses the [jQuery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Comment: JSON is not allowed in cookies for Opera since ancient times http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=663192&t=1358850781&page=1#comment12828912
I also have this error.
Even though if @cookie@ plugin use @encodeURIComponent@, pbug shouldn't appear.

Comment: This question and answer lead me to believe that `cookie` is an inbuilt function in jQuery. It appears to be not. or is it deprecated..? if it is the plugins i find, linking to it would be great to avoid the confusion...

Comment: @TJ It is indeed a plugin, the jQuery cookie plugin. You can find it here: http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/ I really wonder why it's not in core at this point...

Comment: Be careful using this in some browsers. The `,` (comma) character can cause the cookies to not be set correctly within safari and other browsers.

Comment: You can also use this great lightweight cookie library if jQuery is not wanted .  [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie] lib

Comment: It seems that commas are disallowed in cookie values as they might be interpreted as separators... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie Would it not be a problem if I directly use `JSON.stringify()`, which might produce commas?

Comment: Seems that using `encodeURLComponent` after `JSON.stringify` solves it. Then when reading the cookie one also needs to first decode it before running `JSON.parse`

Answer (score 40):

Now there is already no need to use `JSON.stringify` explicitly. Just execute this line of code

```
$.cookie.json = true;
```

After that you can save any object in cookie, which will be automatically converted to JSON and back from JSON when reading cookie.

```
var user = { name: "name", age: 25 }
$.cookie('user', user);
...

var currentUser = $.cookie('user');
alert('User name is ' + currentUser.name);
```

But JSON library does not come with jquery.cookie, so you have to download it by yourself and include into html page before [jquery.cookie.js](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Comment: I tried this approach without $.cookie.json = true and got [object object] as my cookie value. Then set it to true and tried to pass the object directly to the cookie and no cookie was populated.

Comment: @jacobross85 I think it's possible that some of us might be using an older version of jquery.cookie.js, please check the source code, sometimes the wrong file is active.

Comment: Please note this will cause cookies to be universally treated as JSON. As a result, blindly adding `$cookie.json = true` can cause conflicts with your other cookies. So be careful using this on a project that already uses cookies elsewhere!

Comment: do you have any solution for complex json? i have an json array in my json which some attributes contains json and  ....

Answer (score 7):

use `JSON.stringify(userData)` to coverty json object to string.

```
var dataStore = $.cookie("basket-data", JSON.stringify($("#ArticlesHolder").data()));
```

and for getting back from cookie use `JSON.parse()`

```
var data=JSON.parse($.cookie("basket-data"))
```

Answer (score 5):

It is not good practice to save the value that is returned from `JSON.stringify(userData)` to a cookie; it can lead to a bug in some browsers.

Before using it, you should convert it to *base64* (using `btoa`), and when reading it, convert from *base64* (using `atob`).

```
val = JSON.stringify(userData)
val = btoa(val)

write_cookie(val)
```

Comment: Do you have an reference to a browser that has trouble with this?

Comment: i use a list of jsons as a cookie on chrome on django platform. it has some issues. also, its always better to hide the actual data passed by the cookie from the user

Comment: On the server side, Python's standard cookie handling will reject cookies containing `{` or `}`, and silently drop any cookies that follow the rejected cookie in the cookie header.

Comment: Cookie spec in [RFC6265](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.1) disallows characters such as `"`. This may lead to server ignoring some cookies from the request.

Answer (score 2):

With serialize the data as JSON and Base64, dependency jquery.cookie.js :

```
var putCookieObj = function(key, value) {
    $.cookie(key, btoa(JSON.stringify(value)));
}

var getCookieObj = function (key) {
    var cookie = $.cookie(key);
    if (typeof cookie === "undefined") return null;
    return JSON.parse(atob(cookie));
}
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
https://github.com/tantau-horia/jquery-SuperCookie

> Quick Usage:
>
> create - create cookie
>
> check - check existance
>
> verify - verify cookie value if JSON
>
> check_index - verify if index exists in JSON
>
> read_values - read cookie value as string
>
> read_JSON - read cookie value as JSON object
>
> read_value - read value of index stored in JSON object
>
> replace_value - replace value from a specified index stored in JSON object
>
> remove_value - remove value and index stored in JSON object

Just use:

```
$.super_cookie().create("name_of_the_cookie",name_field_1:"value1",name_field_2:"value2"});
$.super_cookie().read_json("name_of_the_cookie");
```