# jQuery.cookie not storing my JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, cookies

So I'm new to jQuery and JSON but this is pretty straight forward and the fact the it isn't working is frustrating me.

I have an ASP.NET MVC Web site. I'm using AJAX (through jQuery) to load some data. Everything is well and good up until there.

I'm trying to store my result in a cookie by using carhartl / jquery-cookie.

The problem is when I try to store my data in a cookie the data isn't really stored. I'm using the code below:

```
                var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(result);

                jQuery.cookie("resultData", jsonObj, {
                    expires: 2,
                    path: "/",
                    json: true
                });
```

`jQuery.cookie("resultData")` returns null

I've tried running the same code but instead of my actual data I wrote "hello word" which worked just fine.

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: What's the size of your json ? You have a limit of 4K for each cookie, I think :)

Comment: 7808 characters, is it the problem ?

Comment: @Johny, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key The overall length of the cookie should not exceed 4096 bytes..

Comment: As I said: 4KB. Try with a smaller json. Like { test : 1 } and see the result

Comment: @Mihai and [at]Gaby aka G. Petrioli yep that's the problem ... lame. Thanks though if [at]Mihai puts this as an answer I can mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: If you don't need cookies why not use jStorage instead? http://www.jstorage.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max size of a cookie is 4 KB. Check that :)
Try with a smaller json, like { test : 1 } and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is that `json: true` is not an option, but it's the property of `jQuery.cookie` object itself.

So you should execute this line somewhere before your code:

```
jQuery.cookie.json = true;
```

and after that execute your code.

So, it could be something like that:

```
jQuery.cookie.json = true;

jQuery.cookie("resultData", jsonObj, {
    expires: 2,
    path: "/"
});
```

And note that, if you set `$.cookie.json = true`, you don't need to json-stringify your object - it would be provided automatically.

Please refer to [official doc](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#json) or [answer on similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14468663/19206713).