# How to add/push new value to an array that stored in cookie by using JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, cookies

I used jQuery to create a cookie `album_like` that store an array of `id`, I would like to add/push new value to this array when some condition met, below is my code

```
if (typeof $.cookie('album_like') == 'undefined') {
    $.cookie('album_like', [data.album_id], { expires: 365, path: '/' });
} else {
    var arr = [$.cookie('album_like')];
    if (!($.inArray(data.album_id, arr) > 0)) {
        arr.push(data.album_id);
        $.cookie('album_like', arr);
    }
}
```

I found that the array become `["1, 2, 3, 4, 5"]` when I use firebug to check the value, so the code `!($.inArray(data.album_id, arr) > 0)` not work, I think the array should be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

Anyone could give some advice on my code?

Thanks

Comment: I've never used jQuery Cookie, but it sounds like things aren't getting JSON encoded/decoded. Try setting `$.cookie.json = true;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is getting you a string as an array entry not an array.

```
 var arr = [$.cookie('album_like')];
```

Try this:

```
var arr = $.cookie('album_like').split(', '); // split string to array
$.each(arr, function(i,v){
    arr[i] = parseInt(v); // convert string array entries to ints
});
```

---

Or you could use json encoding to store and retrieve the array [jquery save json data object in cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225030/jquery-save-json-data-object-in-cookie)

```
 $.cookie.json = true;
```

Comment: @Charles, which one did you use?