# Store, edit and share javascript variable value

Tags: javascript

There is a javascript variable that contains a list of numbers. 

 1) I want the user to be able to modify that list. 
2) I want that list to stay preserved so that it can be shared between pages.

How can I do this?

Assumptions: There are no concurrent users.

Note: I dont want any code but just a textual description of what can be a way of implementing this ?

Comment: This is way, *way* too broad for Stack Overflow. Start building something, and ask a specific, *answerable* question if you get stuck.

Comment: @meagar I hope it is specific now?

Comment: No, it's worse. You can't ask this question here. You're asking us to come up with the UI, the code, the back-end, literally *every part* of the solution. That's not was this site is for. You can't just post a list of **extremely** high-level requirements here and expect a coded solution. As it stands, my answer to the actual question you ask, "how can I do this", is "write a solution in software".

Comment: @meagar I dont want the code or UI or anything but just a general textual description of what can be one of the ways of implementing it.

Comment: Ok. "Use JavaScript. Persist the values somewhere". That is a completely appropriate answer for a question as broad and generic as this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out the solution to this : COOKIES. The more experienced web developers might say "So, what? Big deal??" but for novice users, for this problem you should consider using cookies. Cookies is what you use to store and share small values.

Refer to this wonderful tutorial on cookies: http://www.sitepoint.com/eat-those-cookies-with-jquery/
and a relevant SO post: [jquery save json data object in cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225030/jquery-save-json-data-object-in-cookie)

***To show Javascript Variable Value:*** Use the value as tooltip for a link element.

***To modify Javascript Variable Value:*** Clicking on a link element can call javascript prompt, where the user can enter new values

***To store Javascript Variable Value:*** Store the value in the cookie

***To share among other pages:*** While storing the cookie use {path:"/"}

Also note that maximum size for cookie can be only 4kb. So, store your data wisely.