# I have a javascript class and a object for that class and i want to store that object in local storage and retrieve it?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

In my program i create a object for every connection and i want to retain those objects even after refreshing the webpage.how can achieve that?

```
<script>
var ip=prompt("Enter address of printer:", "12.222.170.99");
conn =new connection();
localStorage.setItem(ip,JSON.stringify(conn));
 var a=localStorage.getItem(ip);
 var b=JSON.parse(a);
b.fun();
function connection()
{
this.fun=function() 
{
alert("hi");`enter code here`
}
}

</script>
```

Comment: `localStorage` is a better option compared to `cookies`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with using a jQuery plugin then you can use

`$.cookie("cookie_name", JSON.stringify(json_object))`

as shown in the following:

[jquery save json data object in cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225030/jquery-save-json-data-object-in-cookie)

This uses the [jQueryCookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin.

An Alternative is to use `localStorage`

```
// Store the object after you stringify it
localStorage.setItem('name', JSON.stringify(json_object));

// Get the object from storage and parse it back to json
var retrievedObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('name'));
```