# Added row to a table with jQuery but added rows disappear with browser refresh

Tags: jquery, html, html-table, row

I added rows to a html table with jQuery, but when I refresh the browser, the rows disappear.  How can I get the rows to stay?

```
<TABLE id="dataTable" width="100%" align="center">
    <TR align="center" border="1">
        <TH></TH>
        <TH>ID </TH>
        <TH>Name</TH>
        <TH>Status</TH>
    </TR>
    <TR align="center">
        <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD>
        <TD> 1 </TD>
        <TD> <INPUT type="text" value="Submission 1" /> </TD>
        <TD>Working version</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#createNew').click(function() {
    var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    $('#dataTable tr:last').after('<TR align="center"><TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD><TD>'+ rowCount + '</TD><TD> <INPUT type="text" value="Submission 1" />   </TD><TD>Working version</TD></TR>');
```

Comment: The html is rendered from the file each time the page is requested - if you want to save changes to need to store the changes somewhere and display them on load ... are you using a server side language ?

Comment: You need to record the creation of the rows somehow (such as an `<input type="hidden">` for instance) and then recreate the rows again when the page shows.  Are you using any server-side coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a suggestion, but You can try to store Your new rows in cookie, like shown here:
[how to store an array in jquery cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959455/how-to-store-an-array-in-jquery-cookie)

This way after page refresh You will get Your rows back (of course You need to read cookie and add rows when page is loaded again).

But the best solution would be to use server-side code to store new rows into database and load them every time You refresh page, this way new records will be visible for everyone who will access that page (or only for specific user if You'll add user identification, but that's bit off Your question).

Check article from @Kell answer, this is really easy to implement :)

Answer (score 0):

With only jQuery you can't.

You need to save your change on a database for example.

Edit : Or you can use php, $_SESSION, $_COOKIE .... I don't know, you have lots of way, but not with only jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on where you are getting the data from to create the table in the first place. If you are retrieving data from a database and sticking it into a tablem, you're going to need to insert the data into the database with your jquery by making an ajax callback.

see [this for details](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/05/insert-and-load-record-using-jquery-and.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.data` function to bind the data to the table and then copy it as many times as possible?? `.data` prevents data from memory leaks you can check the same at `api.jquery.com`