# How to store every content of an array in cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to store an array in jquery cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959455/how-to-store-an-array-in-jquery-cookie)

How to store every content of an array in cookie in javascript and also i have to retrive all the term of an array?
 I tried but i am not able to retrive items back from cookie....

My code is below wat i tried

```
var myArray=["123","234","32"];
$.cookie('myCookie', escape(myArray), { expires: 1});
var s = unescape($.cookie('myCookie');
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) Have you searched for a tutorial on cookies?

Comment: Added the jQuery tag because it looks like that... and now we have a duplicate. It looks like you should just not use `escape` or `unescape`.

Comment: Your code has a typo. Missing the last parentheses at `var s = unescape($.cookie('myCookie');`

Comment: I tried with removal of escape and unescape but didnt get the proper solution. I am able to save the array in cookie but how to retrive the every term that i am not able to do

Comment: If you are using this cookie implementation, it seems you have to set the `json` option to `true`: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#json.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery, you can use serialize function to retrieve all data in string : http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: `.seralize` has not much to do with arrays, it's for converting a form into a query string...

Answer (score 0):

To create a cookie in JavaScript you must assign a string to `document.cookie`.

It takes values in a `name = value` format e.g.

```
document.cookie = 'data=hello; max-age=60; path=/; domain=yoursite.com';
```

The best way to store an array in here is to use [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp) and the method [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```
var arr = ['hello', 'goodbye', 'au revoir'];
document.cookie = 'data=' + escape(JSON.stringify(arr)) + '; max-age=60; path=/; domain=yoursite.com'
```

(Note a cookie must be <= 4KB)

Retrieving the cookie is a little harder as it is a string, so I borrowed this function which searches the string for your cookie name then returns it's value:

```
// Source: http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/cookies.shtml

function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
{
    var cookie_string = document.cookie ;
    if (cookie_string.length != 0) {
        var cookie_value = cookie_string.match (
                        '(^|;)[\s]*' +
                        cookie_name +
                        '=([^;]*)' );
        return decodeURIComponent ( cookie_value[2] ) ;
    }
    return '' ;
}
```

In our example you would use it like this:

```
var cookie = get_cookie('data');
var arr = JSON.parse(cookie); // Convert JSON string back into array
```

Note I use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to convert the JSON string back into a JavaScript array.

For more information on utilising cookies in JavaScript I suggest you read: http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/cookies.shtml