# how to pass an array from one html to another html page?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, cordova

i am using this for **Phonegap** so,i would prefer the solution in javascript.

i found many solutions using **PHP**.thats why i thought of making it clear.

well i get an array,whose vales are from the database.I want to pass this array to the SECOND HTML PAGE.

to pass a variable the following code is being used...

**EDIT:**

```
 window.location.href="1stpage.html"?var1=&value;
```

hope, i am right with the coding.

Please,guide me,if i am wrong.

**changes with reference to the answer suggested**

Julio Meca Hansen Sir,i tried implementing the same

```
 window.location.href='1st page.html?var1=5&var2=6';
```

and tried verifying it by printing the values on the second page...

```
console.log("value1: "+var1 +"value2: "+var2 );
```

alas!,i get this error...

```
E/Web Console(12476): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: var1 at file:///android_asset/www/1st%20page.html?var1=5&var2=6:17
```

Comment: Your code is invalid - JS is different from HTML, you don't wrap them between `<` and `>` signs ;)

Comment: oops, Sorry.i may be stand corrected!

Comment: This is an unusual scenario since you risk the user being able to alter the data. Usually you'd re-retrieve the data from the database between pages.

Comment: SLC,i dont think so...because i am using this concept in Phonegap.i am not gonna get any values from the user.it will be from the database.

Comment: @SLC I beg to differ - sometimes passing strings or arrays between pages can be important, such as a multistep form (well, you can technically do that with cookies, but that doesn't make them any more secure). Pagination leverages a lot on passing various variables between pages, too.

Comment: There are a bunch of reasons why I would never personally do that, such as server side validation, or the user pressing the 'back' button in the browser, or pressing F5, or if a validation error occured on page 1 and you were on page 4, you'd have to get back there and have a nightmare of ensuring you don't lose the information from page 2, 3, 4 when you press 'next' after correcting the mistake. Lots of unnecessary baggage in my opinion, and a monstrosity to program and maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code is linked to an image, it would be more like this:

```
<img src="images/img1.png" alt="" onclick="window.location.href='1stpage.html?var1=5&var2=6';">
```

Modify it to fit your needs :P

Comment: Julio Meca Hansen Sir,thank you.on the first note,i am using mapping,for the on-click....on the second note,i need to pass an **ARRAY** not a variable.

Comment: second page should by php, not html if he/she wants to use $_GET to fetch values.

Comment: Doesn't matter... I wrote `var1=5` but you could easily write `a[sample1]=5` and so on. The ideal would be for you to automatically build the URL parameters with the `http_build_query()` function, but if you're using plain HTML, you need to specify each parameter by hand, being it an array or a simple value.

Comment: Julio Meca Hansen Sir,i am using the basic html. i will try and let you know whether did it work or not.

Comment: Julio Meca Hansen Sir, can i code it this way, 
`<area shape="rect" coords="1,0,84,99" alt="Sun" window.location.href="1stpage.html?var nameArray[]=results.rows.item(i).name";>`

Comment: Of course not, you can't pass an array in a direct fashion. `1stpage.html?var nameArray[]=results.rows.item(i).name"` is not a valid parameter. Let's say i equals to 5 and `results.rows.item(i).name` equals to 'dog'. Your parameter would be like `1stpage.html?nameArray[5]=dog`. As you want to pass some elements calculated dynamically, you should build a javascript function that does the same so, instead of writing `onclick="window.location.href='1stpage.html?var1=5&var2=6';"` you would write something like this: `onclick="goURL();"`, being `goURL()` a javascript function doing what you want.

Comment: Julio Meca Hansen Sir,i tried implementing the same `window.location.href='1st page.html?var1=5&var2=6';` and tried verifying it by printing the values on the second page... `console.log("value1: "+var1 +"value2: "+var2 );` alas!,i get this error...`E/Web Console(12476): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: var1 at file:///android_asset/www/1st%20page.html?var1=5&var2=6:17`

Comment: i am gonna use this method..till i get the output. :P

Answer (score 2):

If this array will only be used by JavaScript, then do NOT use a cookie. Cookies are for storing information that the server needs access to, and setting them willy-nilly can increase your network usage by a significant amount!

Instead, use JavaScript's `localStorage` interface. It is supported by all modern browsers (IE7 and below don't count as "modern", especially with Windows Update practically forcing you to update), and is real easy to use:

```
var someArray = [1,2,3,4];
if( !window.localStorage) alert("Sorry, you're using an ancient browser");
else {
    localStorage.myArray = JSON.stringify(someArray);
}
```

Later, you can retrieve it: `JSON.parse(localStorage.myArray)`

I hope this is what you are trying to achieve. If not, please clarify your question some ;)

Comment: Kolink Sir,could you please let me know the concept of we using the Window .local storage and why are we gonna use **JSON.stringify(someArray);**....we use JSON when you want some dat from online...AM i right???

Comment: `localStorage` can only store strings, and does not serialise values automatically. `JSON` is a means to convert JS objects to a string value. Usually it's used for passing data around online, but not necessarily.

Comment: Kolink,now how should i connect it to the next HTML page?

Comment: You can just redirect with `location.href = '1stpage.html'`, just like that, and retrieve `localStorage` values from there.

Comment: Kolink,i hope you dont mind me asking questions...i am new to javascript.so this code will be on the 1st page.

  `var someArray = [1,2,3,4];
if( !window.localStorage) alert("Sorry, you're using an ancient browser");
else {
    localStorage.myArray = JSON.stringify(someArray);
}`

on the 1st page and later on we should use the following code to retrieve it??

`JSON.parse(localStorage.myArray)`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use javascript:

```
<a href="1stpage.html?var1=5&var2=6">
   <img src="images/img1.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

Comment: lolcat111,i dont want the image src.....i just need to pass an array value from 1 html to another html page.

Comment: But the user must click on a link to get to the next page... The image is just decoration, you can also only put text in the link.

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed you are using jquery but the principle is the same in plain old js - use a cookie e.g.

[how to store an array in jquery cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959455/how-to-store-an-array-in-jquery-cookie)

This actually stores the array rather than a load of variables as described in other answers.

Comment: matpol,i am not using JQUERY...instead i am using javascript.

Comment: did you read the answer the principle is the same in plain old javascript 'set a cookie' (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) - don't mark me down for referencing w3schools but it was the first thing that came up on google!