# Real time data extraction JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have written a code which extracts a specific table from a webpage. The website is dynamic and it updates the values in the table once every half an hour. My Javascript for parsing the website does reload the website once every 30 minutes. But the data extracted as JSON are only data of the particular time. But, I want to append or concatenate all the data every time the site reloads(i.e., i need the present list of data concatenated with previous list, as long as the program is running) How do i do that?.

The webpage is: https://www.emcsg.com/marketdata/priceinformation

The table required is: View 72 periods

My code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Pricing </title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/raw/master/json2.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1800" /><!--Reloads page every 30 minutes-->
<script>

      function requestCrossDomain(site, callback) {
          if (!site) {
              alert('No site was passed.');
              return false;
          }
          var yql = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from html where url="' + site + '"') + '&format=xml&callback=?';
          $.getJSON(yql, cbFunc);
          function cbFunc(data) {
              if (data.results[0]) {
                  data = data.results[0].replace(/<script[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/script>/gi, '');
                      window[callback](data);
              } else throw new Error('Nothing returned from getJSON.');
          }
      }

    var url = 'https://www.emcsg.com/marketdata/priceinformation';
    requestCrossDomain(url, 'someFunction');

    function someFunction(results){
        var html = $(results);
        var table = html.find(".view72PeriodsWrapper");
        $('#loadedContent').css("display","").html(table);

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br><br>
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="loadedContent"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you heard about cron and curl?

Comment: What is the data structure you receive? You could make an array object and push the data to array.

Comment: they both start with c and the first executes the second and the second runs your script page

Comment: and you will need a db or some form of storage

Comment: @madalinivascu i think an array would suffice for my needs. Just need to append the array with newer values as the site refreshes. and have never heard of cron and curl (im a newbie to js)..

Comment: you want the data from emcsg to update as long as the page remains open?

Comment: The data gets updated every half hour as long as the page is open. But  want to store all the data as long as it is open. probably in an array and concatenate the array to add the updated data with the previous data.

Comment: Have you try jquery cookie plugin? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959455/how-to-store-an-array-in-jquery-cookie