# Set and get cookie array of added html elements for each page/url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, jsfiddle

I have a bookmark function that appends a caret (element) to a progress bar (element). The caret is absolutely positioned relative to the progress bar's width. The user can add multiple bookmarks. Resultant HTML;

```
<div class="progress-bar" style="width: 50%;">
    <div class="caret" style=" left:50%;"></div>
    <div class="caret" style=" left:60%;"></div>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is save these bookmarks in a cookie so that when the user revisits the page the bookmarks are in place.

I have the basic setup using this solution [how to store an array in jquery cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959455/how-to-store-an-array-in-jquery-cookie)

But I am stuck as to how to store and show a set of saved bookmark elements and how to do this for each page / url where bookmarks are saved.

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jabuka/spevhqxv/

Thank you.

Comment: you can use localStorage to store the vaue

Comment: Good point - I will work on that rather. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add each element you create to an array, then convert it to a JSON object and store it in local storage, like this:

```
var json = JSON.stringify(elems);
localStorage.setItem('bookmarks', json);
```

When the user revisits the page you can load the JSON page again and add the elements:

```
elems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bookmarks'));
for(var i in elems){
 $('.progress-bar').append(elems[i]);
}
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/martiensk/spevhqxv/97/)

Comment: Awesome thank you. I added a check to see whether the array existed `elems = elems || [];` otherwise it threw an error.

Comment: Glad I could help!