# Add multiple dynamic values in JQuery cookie

Tags: jquery, arrays, cookies

I am currently using this JQuery cookie plugin https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie and it is working for just single cookie value but i want it to work for multiple dynamic values stored in as an array.

For example, i have a list of the products in a page and i am showing "save products" link on each products. I want, clicking on the save button to store an id of the products in same cookies so i can retrieve all the values and display in a separate page.

I will appreciate if you can just show me how to store values in a cookies as an array i will do the rest.

## HTML:

```
<ul>
 <li id="product1">product 1 <a>Save Products</a></li>
 <li id="product2">product 2 <a>Save Products</a></li>
</ul>
```

## JQUERY:

```
$('ul li a').each(function(){
 $('this').click(function(){
  Cookies.set('SavedProducts', { foo: 'bar' });
 });
});
```

Comment: so store an array of the items clicked. `var z = []; z.push("aaaa");` what trouble are you having?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, since orignal cookie only supports TEXT based saving, You should serialize the arrays/tuple before storing as cookie.

Please Refer the following link.
[how to store an array in jquery cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959455/how-to-store-an-array-in-jquery-cookie)

Good Luck