# jquery save multiple cookie for every link

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have lots of links in the page, click each one `addClass` 'voted' to this link. then save the effection into cookies. so that next time refresh web browser, it will save the `addClass` event.

My code here, but it will only save 1 cookie. I mean if I clicked `link 1`, `link 2`. it always remember the last click. refresh the web browser. only `link 2` `addClass` 'voted'. `link1` missed `addClass` event. so how to save multiple cookie for every link? Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var cookieName = 'up';
  var cookieOptions = {expires: 7, path: '/'};  

  $("#" + $.cookie(cookieName)).addClass('voted');

  $(".up").live('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    $.cookie(cookieName, $(this).attr("id"), cookieOptions);
    // save cookie depends on each link id. 
    $("#" + $.cookie(cookieName)).addClass('voted');
  });
});
</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="m12345678" class="up">link 1</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="m12345679" class="up">link 2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="m12345680" class="up">link 3</a>
```

**Upload my code in**: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RQP4T/)

Comment: which `cookie.js` u r using? please provide the link

Comment: @diEcho, `https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. refrence here: [Jquery - save class state for multiple div #'s to a cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101417/jquery-save-class-state-for-multiple-div-s-to-a-cookie)

share the answer to the all.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(function() {
        var cookieName = 'up_';

        $('.up').each(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id'), cookie = cookieName + id;

            if ($.cookie(cookie) !== 'ture') {
                $(this).addClass('voted');
            }
        }).live('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.cookie(cookieName + $(this).attr('id'), true);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

change the cookie-name may resolve the problem.

```
var cn = cookieName + $(this).attr("id");
$.cookie(cn, cookieOptions);
// save cookie depends on each link id. 
$("#" + $.cookie(cn)).addClass('voted');
```

**UPDATE:** this update added to answer to your updated question:

```
function checkIfAllClicked(){
    var flag = false;
    $(".up").each(function(){
        var f = $(this).data("isClicked");
        if(f == true){
            flag = true;
        }
        else{
            flag = false;
        }
    });
    if(flag){
        // refresh the page or call any-other function you want
        document.location.href = "any-url";
    }
}

$(".up").live('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();    
    $.cookie(cookieName, $(this).attr("id"), cookieOptions);
    // save cookie depends on each link id. 
    $("#" + $.cookie(cookieName)).addClass('voted');
    $(this).data("isClicked", true);
    checkIfAllClicked();
});
```

Comment: thanks, so how about the `$("#" + $.cookie(cn)).addClass('voted');` out of the `click`? the js variable can not pass out of the `click`.

Comment: I don't understand what you want really, but if you want to save a data for an element, you can use `$(this).data("your-name","your-value")` and in other `function` you can retrieve the saved data by: `var d = $(selector).data("your-name");`. can you explain your purpose more please?

Comment: upload my code in `http://jsfiddle.net/RQP4T/show/`. I just want to remember all the `clicked` behave. if I clicked all the 3 links, then refresh the web browser, it will remember 3 links addClass. if you are good at it, could you re-write a working code for me? Thanks.

Comment: OK. but your (second) issue is not based on Cookies. You have to set a function to monitor links and when they all are clicked, refresh the page. You can use the $(element).data() method. I update the answer, but you should add the above summery, to the question too.

Comment: @Giberno upvote the answer if it is use-full and accept it if resolved your problem, please

Comment: @king.net, `Uncaught ReferenceError: cookieName is not defined` see `http://jsfiddle.net/RQP4T/1/show/`

Comment: OM!!! I just put the main code in answer! You should complete it! put this lines: `  var cookieName = 'up';
  var cookieOptions = {expires: 7, path: '/'}; `

Comment: @king.net, still not remember addclass after refresh the web browser. `http://jsfiddle.net/RQP4T/2/`. I am less `15 reputation`, sorry for not `make up` your answer.