# JS library that has the the ability to serialize/re-hydrate elements state

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am looking for a component/framework that has the the ability to serialize/re-hydrate the elements, or UI components upon the next page view. Something analogous to `$.serialize()` but for an element's properties (examples: visibility,width, top, left ).

All the functionality in jQuery is there to do this manually,  but I am looking for a framework that has explored the problems/pitfalls of this functionality better than I have to date.

Server side I am using asp.net, but it is really the client-side functionality that I am looking for. I expect the actual state to be persisted in a cookie, or more persistent manner on the server.

I realize the functionality I am looking for is implemented in web parts. I am hoping get a light-weight framework to work with. I am not too excited about investing in web parts.

An example of what I am trying to achieve:
I would like to create a page with 5 to 10 divs, laid out in a grid-live fashion. A dashboard-like UI. there is a default layout, but users can hide some areas & expand others to get the best view of the data that they care about. Aside from just divs, There may be other widgets: tabs, accordions, ect. They do not need to be, but lets assume the UI is powered by jQuery UI. The next time the user logs in, I should be able to restore the state of the page by the user.

Before I begin working on a custom functionality, I want to make sure that I am not re-building a wheel.

Comment: Just to get a better understanding of what you're asking, you're looking for a javascript UI framework that automatically saves an object's state? Every object's state?

Comment: @NT3RP Every Object's state seems like too much to ask for. Lets narrow it down to basic position & visibility... and my imaginary framework would would be extensible enough to allow me to define how to save visual state on something like an Accordion widget..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may wish to look at knockout.js, it's a Model-View View Model javascript framework.

It handles things like syncing DOM elements properties to a model.

Here is the homepage: http://knockoutjs.com/

It has guidence on loading and saving via JSON: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html

However i'd reccomend doing the interactive tutorial first, as it really shows of it's power and will help you gather whether it's suitable for your problem: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/

Comment: This is a compelling Library, and I have wanted to use it. I would not initially thought it would help, but as I went through the tutorials, if I though about the problem a little differently.. perhaps. The main strength is that is provides the ability to work at a higher level of abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could save the state within your database so it's stored with the users session, or you could create some client side code that store's the state within a cookie on the client's machine

Here's a similar example of the second option, to store it within a cookie

[Jquery - save class state for multiple div #'s to a cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101417/jquery-save-class-state-for-multiple-div-s-to-a-cookie)

and the code provided by the post: http://pastebin.me/d99bd40618a7b9e2bd88c40cee777f5f

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I began working directly with cookies, and  I found I was running into low level problems when the problem I was trying to solve was a high-level one.

Answer (score 0):

Check the PersistJS library
http://pablotron.org/?cid=1557

It has lot of features

It currently supports persistent client-side storage through the following backends:

1. flash: Flash 8 persistent storage.
2. gears: Google Gears-based persistent storage.
3. localstorage: HTML5 draft storage.
4. whatwg_db: HTML5 draft database storage.
5. globalstorage: HTML5 draft storage (old spec).
6. ie: Internet Explorer userdata behaviors.
7. cookie: Cookie-based persistent storage.

   - globalStorage: Firefox 2.0+, Internet Explorer 8
   - localStorage: development WebKit
   - openDatabase: Safari 3.1+
   - userdata behavior: Internet Explorer 5.5+

Comment: I think the storing the information is not the real problem. He would like to save the elements states.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was not aware of this lib. It is powerful. however, client side robust persistence is not my main issue here. server side DB will be where this is saved ultimately.