# My Function Is Broken It Seems Javascript

Tags: javascript

Basically no matter what I enter when I call the function it says you have fled. I may just be overlooking something but I can't figure out what.

```
    function attack() {
var battle = prompt("Attack of Flee?")
if (battle === "Flee" || "flee") {
    alert("You have fled");
    } 
else if (battle === "Attack" || "attack"){
    alert("You have attacked");
}   
    }
```

Comment: `battle === "Flee" || "flee"` won't work as you expect. It will compare `battle === "Flee"` (which may or may not be `true`), and then check the truthyness of `"flee"`, which is always `true`. You have to compare `battle` against something each time. Use `battle === "Flee" || battle === "flee"` (and similar for the other comparison). Although I'd suggest just setting the `prompt`'s value to lowercase, and comparing that

Comment: what error does this code throws?? Can you specify the situation?

Comment: @Misters: The code doesn't throw an error.

Comment: `"flee"` is always true, also just force the case using either `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()`. Then we need to only check a single value, no matter how the user typed in there string (case-wise), it will work.

Comment: [javascript - Check variable equality against a list of values - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Or operator not working in IF statement Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089632/or-operator-not-working-in-if-statement-node-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `if (battle === "Flee" || battle === "flee")`
The right hand side is just evaluating the string "flee" for truthiness, which always evaluates `true`.

Comment: The other answers are great! Actually going to do those instead but this one actually did clear the immediate problem.

Answer (score 2):

1. `if (battle === "Flee" || "flee")` in this if condition 
   you should write

   `if (battle === "Flee" || battle === "flee")`

if you want to ignore case then batter if u change string to **lower case** 
here is example

```
function attack() {
    var battle = prompt("Attack of Flee?");
    if (battle.toLowerCase() === "flee") {
        alert("You have fled");
    } else if (battle.toLowerCase() === "attack") {
        alert("You have attacked");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function attack() {
    var battle = prompt("Attack of Flee?");
    var ActionTaken = "";
    if (battle.ToLowerCase() == "flee") {
        ActionTaken = "You have fled";
    } 
    else if (battle.ToLowerCase() == "attack") {
        ActionTaken = "You have attacked";
    }
    alert(ActionTaken);
}
```