# Multiple If else statements only returning first value

Tags: javascript

The code below is only returning the **first** if statement regardless of whether the var product_check is actually equal to the other else if conditions.  Could someone point me in the right direction with this? I'm sure it has to be an easy fix...

```
var product_check = '<?php echo($productLine); ?>';

if (product_check === 'Blades' || 'Ceiling Tiles' || 'Clouds' || 'Partitions' || 'Panels') {
    jQuery('select#input_6_28 option').html('Acoustical Solutions');
} else if (product_check === 'Curva') {
    jQuery('select#input_6_28 option').html('Appliances');
} else if(product_check === 'Acrylic Resin Panels' || 'High Gloss Panels' || 'Super Matte Panels' || 'Modular Cork Wall Panels' || 'Reclaimed Hardwood') {
    jQuery('select#input_6_28 option').html('Architectural Panels');      
}
```

Comment: You can't check multiple values that way (`if (product_check === 'Blades' || 'Ceiling Tiles' `). You need to test each one individually (e.g. `if (product_check === 'Blades' || product_check === 'Ceiling Tiles' `). You could also create an array and use array functions to check against.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check variable equality against a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values)

Comment: You can also use a switch case.

Comment: Why is this tagged PHP? (Not that the problem is that much different in PHP, but still...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check each one individually.

Try this:

```
var product_check = '<?php echo($productLine); ?>';

if (product_check === 'Blades' || product_check === 'Ceiling Tiles' || product_check === 'Clouds' || product_check === 'Partitions' || product_check === 'Panels') {

jQuery('select#input_6_28 option').html('Acoustical Solutions');

} else if (product_check === 'Curva') {

    jQuery('select#input_6_28 option').html('Appliances');

} else if(product_check === 'Acrylic Resin Panels' || product_check === 'High Gloss Panels' || 
product_check === 'Super Matte Panels' || product_check === 'Modular Cork Wall Panels' || product_check ==='Reclaimed Hardwood') {

    jQuery('select#input_6_28 option').html('Architectural Panels');
}
```

Using a `switch` block would be better.

Example:

```
switch (product_check) {
    case 'Curva':
        jQuery('select#input_6_28 option').html('Appliances');
        break;
    case 'Acrylic Resin Panels':
    case 'High Gloss Panels':
    case 'Super Matte Panels':
    case 'Modular Cork Wall Panels':
    case 'Reclaimed Hardwood':
        jQuery('select#input_6_28 option').html('Architectural Panels');
        break;
    default:
        jQuery('select#input_6_28 option').html('Acoustical Solutions');
        break;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you very much!