# How to set a userscript to run on an array of websites?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I want to change some website's background since I hate the current one but to do so I got to use document.location.host. I got a big js file includes another sites so I can't just create another js for this one. Only problem is that site redirects example.com to example1.com, example2.com, example3.com and so on.

So I can use

```
if (document.location.host === example1.com || example2.com ||  example3.com)
```

but I want something more steady so I wouldn't need to write 1000 urls side by side, like example1.com - example1255.com. It must be like

```
if (document.location.host === example[*].com)
```

Now, I know for a fact that this is possible because I did it before. I guess I did it by using i++ method but I don't remember how so this is my question.

How can I use an array to get website? Or is it more like; How can I choose a website with and array?

P.S. I don't want to use stylish or something!
P.P.S. I don't need an equality check. The whole idea is not writing those values but making the script do it.

Comment: Use a regular expression. If you post the actual site names, it would be easier to come up with one.

Comment: `["example1.com", "example2.com","stackoverflow.com"].includes(document.location.host)`

Comment: @RandyCasburn do we really need another answer when there are probably dozens like this already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check variable equality against a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values)

Comment: @vlaz - concur.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I don't need it to check already writen values. The whole idea was me not writing all those values. Like I said I could use if (document.location.host === example1.com || example2.com ||  example3.com .... || example1255.com)

Comment: `/^example\d+\.com$/.test(document.location.host)` ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Tampermonkey, you should use [the `@include`, `@match`, and `@exclude` directives](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_include) to control what pages the script runs on as much as possible.
This increases performance and reduces the risk of side effects.

Tampermonkey also supports limited regex in `@include` (different from pattern matching available in `@match`), so you can use a script like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Run on a subset of pages
// @include  *://example*.com/*
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

//-- Additional check to make sure server is of form example{some optional number}:
if ( ! /example\d*\.com/.test (location.hostname) )
    return;

console.log ("Hello world!");
```

Comment: Thank you for the explaining. Phil answered as same tough it took me a while to understand. It worked!

Comment: You may want to remove "not(!)" logical operator btw.

Comment: What that code block does is execute the `return` (abort the script) if the pattern does not match your requirements.