# Formvalidation with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, validation

i wanted to validate my form but im stuck with the validation of formfield persnr.
It won´t compare the string. For this i already tried the comparison and operators (or || ). The validation of the other fields is ok. Did i use the operators wrong?

```
function checkForm() {
    var strFehler = '';
    if (document.forms[0].user.value == "user")
        strFehler += "user not ok!\n";
    if (document.forms[0].test.value == "")
        strFehler += "test not ok!\n";
    if (document.forms[0].time.value == "")
        strFehler += "time not ok";
    if (document.forms[0].cost.value == "")
        strFehler += "cost not ok!\n";
    if (document.forms[0].persnr.value != "13088") || (document.forms[0].persnr.value != "10286")
    strFehler += "persnr false!\n";
    if (strFehler.length > 0) {
        alert("problems!!: \n\n" + strFehler);
        return (false);
    }
}
```

I expected that the validation would show an alert if the value isn´t 13088 or 10286 but no message pops up.

Comment: The code as posted has a syntax error in the `if` statement for `persnr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
if (document.forms[0].persnr.value != "13088") || (document.forms[0].persnr.value != "10286")
```

Needs to be changed to this:

```
if ((document.forms[0].persnr.value != "13088") || (document.forms[0].persnr.value != "10286"))
```

Your are missing parentheses to have both conditions inside the the *if statement*.

Comment: Yup. OP's browser console should be screaming about this, too. `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '||'`

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem. What would you suggest if i want do compare 5 numbers like in the code above?

Comment: This question might help you on this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4728144/7919626