# JS Refactoring multiple condition and returns boolean

Tags: javascript, refactoring, conditional-formatting

How could I refacto this code ?

```
const toto = 1
const isToto = toto === 1 || toto === 12 || toto === 3 || toto === 4
```

I need toto to be a boolean

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check variable equality against a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values)

Comment: `const isToto =  !!{1:1,12:1,3:1,4:1}[toto];` is fast: no function calls...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a check with more than one value, you could use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) which looks for a value in an array/string.

```js
const
    toto = 1,
    isToto = [1, 12, 3, 4].includes(toto);

console.log(isToto);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, note that `=` is an assignment operator, for comparison you can use `==` or `===`. Now, one solution could be to create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of accepted values and then check if the created set contains the related value stored in `toto` variable:

```js
let toto = 1;
const acceptedValues = new Set([1, 12, 3, 4]);
console.log(acceptedValues.has(toto));
toto = 2;
console.log(acceptedValues.has(toto));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```