# Simplify condition for a variable with multiple conditions OR ​in Java or Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and I want to know if there is a better way to simplify it.
I need to use simple data structures (yes, for each, etc.)

```
function amountDayMonth(month) {
    let amountDayMonth
    if(month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) {
        amountDayMonth = 31;
    } else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11) {
        amountDayMonth = 30;
    } else if(month == 2) {
        amountDayMonth = 28;
    }
    return amountDayMonth;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check variable equality against a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values)

Comment: `return month == 2 ? 28 : [4, 6, 9, 11].includes(month) ? 30 : 31;`

Comment: Don't forget leap years...

Comment: That code would work better if you changed `amountDayMonth == 28;` to `amountDayMonth = 28;`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution by far is to ABUSE the Date object

```
function amountDayMonth(month) {
    return new Date(2019, month, 0).getDate();
}
```

month is 0 based, so using month, you're creating a date of the 0th day in the next month, which is the last day of month .. which is the length of the month

Then you need to fix february if it's a leap year

or

```js
function amountDayMonth(year, month) {
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}
console.log(amountDayMonth(2019, 4)); // 30
console.log(amountDayMonth(2019, 2)); // 28
console.log(amountDayMonth(2020, 2)); // 29
console.log(amountDayMonth(2019,12)); // 31
```

Done

no if's or switch's required

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion to rewrite your logic in one line:

1. use `Number.isInteger(month) && month >= 1 && month <= 12` to check for `undefined`
2. use `month % 2 == +(month <= 7)` to check for `31`
3. use `month == 2` to check for `28`
4. the rest is `30`

```js
function amountDayMonth(month)
{
  return (Number.isInteger(month) && month >= 1 && month <= 12) ? (month % 2 == +(month <= 7) ? 31 : (month == 2 ? 28 : 30)) : undefined
}
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13].forEach(x=>console.log(amountDayMonth(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could preset and array and check against it for expected values like so:

```
const expectedMonths = [1,3,5,7,8,10,12];

if (expectedMonths.indexof(month)>-1) {
    amountDayMonth = 31;
}
```

Or since your data is pretty much static, just have an existing table of values

```
let amountDayMonth = month => [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][month]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array lookup. Showing Java example, since you indicated you want either.

```
private static final int[] DAYS = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
public int amountDayMonth(int month) {
    return DAYS[month - 1];
}
```

If you don't like array like that, you can use ternary operator:

```
public int amountDayMonth(int month) {
    return (month == 2 ? 28 : month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11 ? 30 : month >= 1 && month <= 12 ? 31 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Or `Arrays.asList(4, 6, 9, 11).contains(month)`

Comment: @shmosel That would require boxing the `int` values, which in my opinion is less optimal than an array of size 12.