# multiple OR conditions in IF statement in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, design-patterns, refactoring, reusability

I have a drop-down and depending on what is selected from the drop-down some of the UI fields will become un-visible to the user to fill. I have an IF statement with many different ORs and have the hard-coded value on the condition. I am very new to coding so I don't know what is the best way to do this. I want to have a clean and reusable code. Also the drop-down values are coming from the database and I did not know how to add to my IF without hard-coding them.
Any help will be appreciated.

```
if (value === 'Banana Factory' || value === 'Apple Factory ') {
      this.store1Visable = false;
    } else {
      this.store1Visable = true;
    }
    if (value === 'Pineapple Factory' || value === 'Peanut Factory' || value === 'Kiwi Factory' || value === 'Watermelon Factory') {
      this.store2Visable = false;
    } else {
      this.store2Visable = true;
  }
    if (value === 'Pineapple Factory' || value === 'Peanut Factory' || value === 'Kiwi Factory' || value === 'Watermelon Factory'
        || value === 'Banana Factory' || value === 'Grape Factory' || value === 'Peach Factory' || value === 'Kiwi Factory') {
      this.store3Visable = false;
    } else {
      this.store3Visable = true;
    }
    if (value === 'Pineapple Factory' || value === 'Peanut Factory' || value === 'Kiwi Factory' || value === 'Watermelon Factory'
        || value === 'Banana Factory' || value === 'Grape Factory' || value === 'Peach Factory') {
      this.store4Visable = false;
    } else {
      this.store4Visable = true;
    }
```

I want my code to be clean and reusable to the point if something needs to be added it be an easy change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check variable equality against a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an array of arrays, one sub-array for each "visable" property, and check to see if the first word of the `value` is included in the array:

```
const allVisiblesValues = [
  ['Banana', 'Apple'],
  ['Pineapple', 'Peanut', 'Kiwi', 'Watermelon'],
  ['Pineapple','Peanut','Kiwi','Watermelon', 'Banana','Grape','Peach','Kiwi'],
  ['Pineapple','Peanut','Kiwi','Watermelon', 'Banana','Grape','Peach']
];

// ...

// Extract first word of value:
const valuePrefix = value.split(' ')[0];
allVisiblesValues.forEach((visibleValuesArr, i) => {
  this['store' + (i + 1) + 'Visable'] = visibleValuesArr.includes(valuePrefix);
});
```

You might also consider changing the code such that:

- `store1Visable`'s spelling (and the others) are corrected to `store1Visible`, etc
- Or, even better - use an array of stores instead of 4 standalone properties, eg, in the `forEach`:

  ```
  this.stores[i] = visibleValuesArr.includes(valuePrefix);
  ```

  Or, use `.map` instead:

  ```
  this.stores = allVisiblesValues.map(
    visibleValuesArr => visibleValuesArr.includes(valuePrefix)
  );
  ```
- Your existing code has a trailing space: `value === 'Apple Factory '`. If that code is working, it would probably be best to change the HTML (or whatever the value comes from) so that the trailing space is removed.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward solution is here:

```
// store all needed values in appropriate arrays
const visibiles1 = ['Banana Factory', 'Apple Factory'];
const visibiles2 = ['Pineapple Factory', 'Peanut Factory', 'Kiwi Factory', 'Watermelon Factory'];
const visibiles3_4 = ['Pineapple Factory', 'Peanut Factory', 'Kiwi Factory', 'Watermelon Factory', 'Banana Factory', 'Grape Factory', 'Peach Factory'];

// then check if 'value' exists in an appropriate array
// if it is - expression on the right will return 'true'
this.store1Visible = visibiles1.includes(value);
this.store2Visible = visibiles2.includes(value);
this.store3Visible = visibiles3_4.includes(value);
this.store4Visible = visibiles3_4.includes(value);
```

You can look at sort of implementation of it here: [JsBin](https://jsbin.com/cixaluc/edit?html,js,output)