# How to convert this code by using find or indexOf?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i created multiple conditions by using map, but i think there are other methods to optimize this code:

```
 if (content.risks) {
    content.risks.map((risk) => {
      if (risk.coverageCode === "PUB" || risk.coverageCode === "SPPI" || risk.coverageCode === "PROD" || risk.coverageCode === "PR" || risk.coverageCode === "DO") {
        risk._class = "com.generali.gip.local.hk.domain.RiskPublicLiability";
      }
      if (risk.coverageCode === "PD") {
        risk._class = "com.generali.gip.local.hk.domain.RiskMaterialDamage";
      }
      if (risk.coverageCode === "BI") {
        risk._class = "com.generali.gip.local.hk.domain.RiskBusinessInterruption";
      }
    });
  }
```

How i can to rewrite this code by using find or indexof?

Comment: For each would be the way to go and you are already doing that, because you don&#39;t return anything in your mapper. Just change the map to forEach and you&#39;re done.

Comment: Where did you learn to use `map` where you should be using `for-of` or `forEach`? I see a lot of this, and would really like to know who's teaching this antipattern so I can have a word with them. :-)

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel so you dont suggest me to use .find or indexOf? Something like this: ` ["PUB", "SPPI", ....].indexOf(risk.coverageCode) >= 0` ?

Comment: *"How i can to rewrite this code by using find or indexof?"* Neither would be a good choice. You can't use `indexOf` because you're looking for matches based on a property on the object, not the object itself, so it would need to be `find`. Using `find` would mean looping through the array (in `find`) repeatedly. Your current solution loops through once, which is more appropriate. (Just use the right looping construct.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'd also like to have a word...It's one of my top pet peeves about programming.

Comment: You could use a switch

Comment: @customcommander what needs optimising, then? Where is the problem and what is the desired outcome? I can't see these details and it's not clear from reading the code what those would be.

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel - Yeah, `switch` within `for-of` or `forEach` would be good. Or at least adding the `else`s, but I like `switch` for the above.

Comment: To map a value to another value, the simpler approach is to use a map :-) e.g. `{PUB: "com.pub...", PD: "com.pd..."}`

Comment: @customcommander - That does mean repeating the target value for five of them (`"PUB"`, `"SPPI"`, ...). But also a reasonable approach, perhaps with an actual Map rather than an object...

Comment: Ok, so the best way is replace map to forEach?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes I was aware of that but in my opinion the "duplication" wouldn't come a the cost of readability (although YMMV of course). All these if statements really get in the way of expressing the _intent_.

Comment: Note that `.forEach` won't "optimise" anything. It's merely making the code work more correctly.

Comment: @VLAZ - Well, `forEach` instead of `map` saves creating a pointless array.  It's unlikely to matter, though. :-)

Comment: @VLAZ ok so, i have a lot of ||, how i can optimize this? Using an array? Sum?

Comment: @Mantegnous - You've been given lots of suggestions for how to restructure the interior of the loop. `switch`, a lookup object, a lookup Map, ...

Comment: @Mantegnous [Check variable equality against a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values)

Comment: @VLAZ can i use `["a","b","C"].some(item => item === opj.field) ` ?

Comment: @Mantegnous yes, you can.

Answer (score 0):

My objective in software development is to express my intents in a way that is clear and unambiguous.

For this kind of "problems", I will always reach out for the humble map. There's no extra ceremonies (i.e. if/else, switch/case, etc.). It just says *"if you give me an X, I'll give you a Y"*.

```
const risk_map =
  { PUB: "com.generali.gip.local.hk.domain.RiskPublicLiability"
  , SPPI: "com.generali.gip.local.hk.domain.RiskPublicLiability"
  , PROD: "com.generali.gip.local.hk.domain.RiskPublicLiability"
  , PR: "com.generali.gip.local.hk.domain.RiskPublicLiability"
  , DO: "com.generali.gip.local.hk.domain.RiskPublicLiability"
  , PD: "com.generali.gip.local.hk.domain.RiskMaterialDamage";
  , BI: "com.generali.gip.local.hk.domain.RiskBusinessInterruption"
  };
```

Regardless of your programming background, the "time to get it" is low.

It *can* indeed lead to duplication but I don't think it comes at the expense of readability or maintenance. *(How hard would it be to replace these duplicated strings with a constant for example?)*

Now how can we "query" this map? Let's build a high-order function for that:

We say *"Give me a map, then give me a key, I'll get you a value"*:

```js
const get_value = map => key => map[key];
get_value(risk_map)("PUB");
//=> "com.generali.gip.local.hk.domain.RiskPublicLiability"
```

The `get_value` is a high-order function. We're meant to build specialised functions out of it. Let's just do that:

```js
const get_risk = get_value(risk_map);
get_risk("PUB");
//=> "com.generali.gip.local.hk.domain.RiskPublicLiability"
```

With this we can solve your "problem" quite simply:

```js
const content_risks =
  content.risks
    ? content.risks.map(risk => get_risk(risk.coverageCode))
    : null;
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to combine and adapt this to fit your exact needs.

Hope this helps though.