# Write a function that accepts a string and returns a new string with just the vowels

Tags: javascript, string

I need help figuring out what is wrong with my code. I think the logic makes sense, but I'm not sure why it's not working.

```
function vowelsOnly(str) {
  var string2 = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
  if(str[i] === "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u"){
    string2 += (str[i]);
  }
  }
  return string2;
}
```

Comment: Your code says:  If the value at index i is equal to "a" or if "e" is truthy. That is not how you check if something is equal to many things.

Comment: A regular expression would be a lot cleaner

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to repeat the complete condition everytime like this:

```
function vowelsOnly(str) {
  var string2 = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) { 
      if(str[i] === "a" || str[i] === "e" || 
      str[i] === "i" || str[i] === "o" ||
      str[i] === "u") { 
      string2 += (str[i]); 
      }
   }
 return string2; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the condition like so:

```
function vowelsOnly(str) {
  var string2 = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
  if(str[i] === "a" || str[i] === "e" || str[i] === "i" || str[i] === "o" || str[i] === "u"){
    string2 += (str[i]);
  }
  }
  return string2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another way is by regExp and replace method.

```js
function vowelsOnly(str) {
 return str.replace(/[^aeiouAEIOU]/gi, '')
}
console.log(vowelsOnly("hello"));


function disemvowel(str) {
return str.replace(/[aeiouAEIOU]/gi, '');
}
console.log(disemvowel("hello"));
```