# Google Script OR Statment

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, logical-operators, logical-or

I am using google script editor to automate a hiring chart that allows different tasks complete (ex. creation of email account) to trigger an email to the next person to complete their task (ex. adding them to payroll)

I am using the `triggerOnEdit(e)` function along with the `var rang = e.range;` to get the active row the changes took place on the sheet and defining the column for each task.

My current issue is I am trying to use an OR statement to allow an email to be sent to the same person depending on what building is defined in the building column.

```
function buildingEmail(e)
{
  var range2 = e.range;
  var row2 = range2.getRow();
  var building2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row2,3).getValue();
  //var building = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(30,3).getValue();
  
    
  if(building2 == ('building 1'||'building 2'))
  {
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Email sent to building 1 Admin");
  MailApp.sendEmail(prEmail,"New Staff Onboarding","A change has been made to the Onboarding Sheet that needs your attention. Please visit link to complete your task.");
  return;
  }
```

I am using `||` because in some google searches that seemed to be how to do an OR statement but that does not seem to be working. I have tried finding how to properly do it now but cannot seem to figure this out. Any assistance on this?

If I need to upload the entire script I can but if someone knows how to add in an OR statement I think the rest of it is working properly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check variable equality against a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values)

Answer (score 2):

Cooper's answer, at least at the moment I am posting this, is almost correct. There is just an extra parenthesis at the end. A somewhat cleaner version might be:

```
if(building2 == 'building 1' || building2 == 'building 2'){
  // Do stuff when either condition is true.
}
```

But beyond the unnecessary parenthesis it is really just a mater of personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(building2=='building 1'|| building2=='building 2'))
```