# chack if a String has at least one of these words

Tags: javascript

instead of doing something like:

```
 if( myString.includes("book")||myString.includes("red")||myString.includes("pen")){
    ...
  }
```

I need something like:

```
 if( myString.includesAnyOf("book","red","pen")){
    ...
  }
```

a pure Js or a Lodash solution would work for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check variable equality against a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values)

Comment: what about using regex?

Comment: You can refer this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript)

Comment: yeah, using `includes` with array of values is more preferable here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Simple regular expression](https://regexper.com/#%2F%28book%7Cred%7Cpen%29%2F) with test

```js
var words = /(book|red|pen)/;
console.log(words.test("I use a pen."));
console.log(words.test("I use a red hen."));
console.log(words.test("I use a blue book."));
console.log(words.test("I use a hen."));
console.log(words.test("I use an open door."));
```

If you want to do string method it is [Array some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [String includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

```js
var words = ["book","red","pen"];

const checkString = str =>
  words.some(word => str.includes(word));
  
  
console.log(checkString("I use a pen."));
console.log(checkString("I use a red hen."));
console.log(checkString("I use a blue book."));
console.log(checkString("I use a hen."));
console.log(checkString("I use an open door."));
```

Comment: You can remove the capturing group `/book|red|pen/`

Comment: thanks indeed for your answer, I wish others had you patience and would first read/understand my question instead of just throwing some -1 at me!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
["book","red","pen"].some(ele => string.includes(ele));
```

```js
function stringCheck(string){
  return ["book","red","pen"].some(ele => string.includes(ele));
}

console.log(stringCheck("testing for words"));
console.log(stringCheck("what if I use book?"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter

```
["book","red","pen"].filter(value => myString.includes(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built-in that will do that for you, you'll have to write a function for it or use this one liner that takes the map function for advantage:

```
substringsArray.some(substring=>yourBigString.includes(substring))
```

if you're looking for a more readable solution, then looping through an array would suffice.

```
const yourstring = 'some string'; // the string to check against
const substrings = ['foo','bar']; // search keys

while(substrings.length--) {
   if(yourstring.indexOf(substrings[length])!=-1) {
       // one of the substrings is in yourstring
   }
}
```