# How to shorten this if else statement?

Tags: javascript

I'm beginning to understand JavaScript now but I try to understand how I can shorten a if else statement like this.

```js
let today = prompt('Enter day').toLowerCase();

if(today === 'monday' || today === 'tuesday' || today === 'wednesday' || today === 'friday') {
    console.log(`${today.replace(/^\w/, (c) => c.toUpperCase())} is a work day.`);
} else if(today === 'saturday' || today === 'sunday') {
    console.log(`${today.replace(/^\w/, (c) => c.toUpperCase())} is weekend day.`);
}
```

Comment: you can [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) your approach this way.

Comment: For readability, you can define a function `isWeekday()` - this will make your posted logic just a simple `if (isWeekday()) { /* code */ } else { /* code */ }`. You can use a `switch` statement as well, but since you're switching on `string`s, you won't get any real performance benefit from the `switch` at all. The function approach is nicer, in my opinion. Note, this question is likely to generate an opinion-based set of answers...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check variable equality against a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values)

Comment: That's almost exactly what the w3schools example is for the use of a switch statement. See the first example: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp Swap out the switch for your prompt and make each case the `today === etc`

Comment: @srWebDev yep, except in that example they are switching on an integer value (contiguous, too!), therefore actually benefitting from the switch.  Good example though!

Answer (score 2):

My approach

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            const today = prompt("Enter day");
            const days = {weekdays: ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday"], weekends: ["saturday", "sunday"]}
            days.weekdays.includes(today) ? document.write(`${today.replace(/^\w/, (c) => c.toUpperCase())} is a work day.`) : (days.weekends.includes(today) ? document.write(`${today.replace(/^\w/, (c) => c.toUpperCase())} is weekend day.`) : console.log(`${today} is not a day`));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let today = prompt('Enter day').toLowerCase();

let weekdays = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'friday']
let weekends = ['saturday', 'sunday']

let dayString = weekdays.includes(today) ?  ` is a work day.` : weekends.includes(today) ? ` is weekend day.`: '';
let finalString = `${today.replace(/^\w/, (c) => c.toUpperCase())}` + dayString;

console.log(finalString);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Accually this was what I was looking for. To take the data from an array. Thanks man!

Comment: Probably, thats the shortest possible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming here that we don't have much info from you, and this kind of snippets could have some other issues before being considered "solid"

Just for the sake of the question...
I'd make the snippet shorter like this:

```
let workOrWeekendDay =
today === "saturday" || today === "sunday" ? "weekend" : "a work";

console.log(
`${today.replace(/^\w/, (c) => c.toUpperCase())} is ${workOrWeekendDay} day.`
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I wanted to know! Cheers man!

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular expressions

```
if(/monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday/.test(today))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [includes()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp) method.

```js
let today = prompt('Enter day').toLowerCase();

if('monday tuesday wednesday friday'.split(' ').includes(today)) {
    console.log(`${today.replace(/^\w/, (c) => c.toUpperCase())} is a work day.`);
} else if(['saturday', 'sunday'].includes(today)) {
    console.log(`${today.replace(/^\w/, (c) => c.toUpperCase())} is weekend day.`);
}
```

In the first use above, we also employ split() in order to condense the list a little bit. This only really helps with particularly long lists. And there is a performance hit the longer the string is, so this is just to give you an idea of some options that might work for you if it is a rarely used piece of code.

In the weekend case, an explicit list is defined without split(). I find this approach better for small lists. Predefining the list may help with readability and anywhere that the comparison is used multiple times. Ex:

```
const weekend = ['saturday', 'sunday'];
if (weekend.includes(today)) ...
```