# How to show a button after one of the two buttons are clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I want two buttons to appear right after one of the two buttons prior is pressed.

```js
var a = "Jeg heter ";
var b = "Benjamin";
var j = "Jasmin";

function endre() {
  var x = document.getElementById("endre1");
  if (x.innerHTML == "Velg navn" || j) {
      x.innerHTML = a + b;
  }
}

function endre2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("endre1");
  if (x.innerHTML == "Velg navn" || b) {
      x.innerHTML = a + j;
   }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="endre2()">Jasmin</button>
<button onclick="endre()">Benjamin</button>
<div id="endre1">Velg navn</div>
<br>
<button class="visknapp24()" style="display: none;">24 år</button>
<button class="visknapp20()" style="display: none;">20 år</button>
```

Any way to add to this?

Comment: Please add some more details, where are you stuck implementing that?

Comment: I don't think `x.innerHTML == "Velg navn" || j` does what you think it does. You aren't comparing the content against two strings, you are comparing against one, and if it's not equal,  `j`s value `"Jasmin"` is being evaluated as `true` (since it's a non empty string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check variable equality against a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need the same function to show for both the buttons. Also, you have to just query the buttons using either `querySelector()` or `getElementsByClassName()`.

Once you have that you can use `style` property from JS to modify CSS styles:

```js
var a = "Jeg heter ";
    var b = "Benjamin";
    var j = "Jasmin";

    function endre() {
    var x = document.querySelector(".visknapp24");
    var y = document.querySelector(".visknapp20");
   x.style.display = 'block';
   y.style.display = 'block';
   
}
```

```html
<button onclick="endre()">Jasmin</button>
<button onclick="endre()">Benjamin</button>
<div id="endre1">Velg navn</div>
<br>
<button class="visknapp24" style="display: none;">24 år</button>
<button class="visknapp20" style="display: none;">20 år</button>
```

Comment: "using either `querySelector()` or `getElementsByClassName()`" Those functions return two very different results. Making them seem equivalent leads to duplicates of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method

Answer (score 1):

You would add an id to your buttons, then update the style.

```html
<button id='btn1' class="visknapp20()" style="display: none;">20 år</button>
```

```js
function endre() {
  var x = document.getElementById("endre1");
  if (x.innerHTML == "Velg navn" || j) {
      x.innerHTML = a + b;
      document.getElementById("btn1").style.display='inline'
  }
}
```

It might be better to use the `visibility` style verses the `display` style.