# Redirect to url if not on specific domains

Tags: javascript

I want the page to redirect to https://example.com if the domain is not on either https://example.com or https://example.site or https://example.page. So far I tried this:

```js
if(location.host != "example.com", "example.site", "example.dev") {
    window.location.replace("https://example.com");
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Check variable equality against a list of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728144/check-variable-equality-against-a-list-of-values)

Comment: That hasn't really worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `indexOf()` method, like this:

```js
const hosts = [
  "example.com",
  "example.site",
  "example.dev",
  "stacksnippets.net" // This website
];

if (hosts.indexOf(location.host) > -1) {
  // Redirect
  console.log('redirect');
}
```