# Sorting, removing, and appending elements using jQuery isn't working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, sorting

This function that sorts my links works like a charm on Chrome/Safari/Firefox but not in IE. Can someone tell me why?

Symptom: everything disappears (line2) nothing appears (line3)

**HTML:**

> ```html
>  <div class="genres">
>    <a title="90 items" href="?genre=absurdism"><span>absurdism</span></a>
>    <a title="83 items" href="?genre=action"><span>action</span></a>
>    <a title="322 items" href="?genre=adult"><span>adult</span></a>
>    <a title="2974 items" href="?genre=adventure"><span>adventure</span></a>
>    <a title="106 items" href="?genre=about+comics"><span>about comics</span></a>
>  </div>
> ```

**SCRIPT**:

```html
sorted = $('.genres a').sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML
});
$('.genres').html('');
sorted.each(function(i, a) {
    $('.genres').append(a)
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MWkJg/2/

The online page of this code is on http://www.lambiek.net/webshop.html (click on "genre" button)

Comment: Did not work in chrome, historical was before art

Comment: If you want to show us live code, please use [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, otherwise as soon as you've solved your problem the question becomes immediately less-useful to others. Plus JS Fiddle's easier for us to *see* and *edit* the code in place, rather than playing in the DOM inspector tools, or having to make our *own* experimental demo.

Comment: The code you gave [works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/MWkJg/), though using `.innerHTML` for sorting, and including the `<span>` in there isn't very nice.

Comment: (Re. the sorting not working in Chrome) Is it possible that the `innerHTML` for some of your genre links starts with something other than the opening `<span>` in your examples?  For instance, some whitespace?  If I modify @CrazyTrain's Fiddle and add newlines between just some of the `<a>`s and their opening `<span>`s, it fails as stated.

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddle you made, also that one isnt the solution for IE

Comment: I was wrong, it's not working, but get rid of the `.html('');` call. There's no reason for it. And then use `.localeCompare()` to compare the values, and it works... though I still say it's not nice to use `.innerHTML` like that.

Answer (score 4):

You need to replace this:

```
$('.genres').html('');
```

with

```
$('.genres').empty();
```

`html` uses the `innerHTML` property to remove contents, and this is handled inconsistently among browsers as you have just seen. `empty`, however, uses the `removeChild` method, and works consistently across browsers. (Incidentally jQuery 2.0 uses `textContent`.)

Also, for your `sort` method to work consistently, it needs to return a numeric value:

```
var sorted = $('.genres a').sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.innerHTML < b.innerHTML ? -1 :
            a.innerHTML === b.innerHTML ? 0 :
            1;
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MWkJg/4/)**

Comment: `.empty()` works like a charm in IE.  If `.html()` is used in IE for emptying html content, it leads to lot of weird behaviours if the content is replaced again with other nodes.  Great Answer. This answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the comparison function passed to the sort method return a number instead of a boolean, i.e.

```
if (a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML) { return 1; };
```

Possible duplicate of [JS sort works in Firefox but not IE - can't work out why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956432/js-sort-works-in-firefox-but-not-ie-cant-work-out-why).

Comment: For the sorting part, yes, but other parts of both questions don't overlap.

Comment: Apologies, I'd not considered the innerHTML problem.