# How to check multiple elements in array with one if with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have 1 or more items in an array, for this example let's say they are `[65, 66, 67]` how can (if it's even possible) do only a single if conditional to check for a match.

For example:

```
var keyArray = [65, 66, 67];
if(e.keyCode == any item in keyArray){
   //Then do this
}
```

Try to make a jQuery plugin that a user can map multiple keys to a single action. E.g. pressing a, b, or c could alert "You're pressing either a, b, or c";

Here is my real sample code that isn't working:

```
$this.keydown(function(e){
            if(e.keyCode in keySplit){
                if(typeof callback == 'function'){
                    callback();
                    e.preventDefault();
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Search for `Array.prototype.indexOf`. eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-ie-browsers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) method in jQuery for that.

> Description: Search for a specified
>   value within an array and return its
>   index (or -1 if not found).

[Or see `in_array` javascript function in phpjs.](http://phpjs.org/functions/in_array:432)

Answer (score 4):

In modern browsers you have [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method. For older browsers it's very easy to create a similar method:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement) {
    var len = this.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       if (this[i] === searchElement)
         return i;
    }
    return -1;
  };
}
```

Now you conditionally defined [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), so it will be available in every platform. Your code becomes:

```
var keyArray = [65, 66, 67];
if ( keyArray.indexOf( e.keyCode ) > -1 ) {
  //Then do this
}
```

​*note, if you want to fully replicate the `Array.indexOf`, see: [MDC indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)*

Answer (score 1):

The "in" operator only sees the keys, not the values, and the keys of [65,66,67] are, of course, [0,1,2]. So you'd check using:

```
var keyArray = {65:65, 66:66, 67:67};
if (e.keyCode in keyArray) {
 // whatever
}
```

The keyArray could as well be {65:"", 66:"", 67:""}; again, it's the key of the key-value pair that counts.

Comment: galambalazs's answer is better. I wasn't aware of Array.indexOf in javascript.