# How can I implement Ruby's Array.include? in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript

I have an array `tempArray = ["Kathmandu","Pokhara","Dharan"]`. To make sure that "Pokhara" is in tempArry, I have to use loop and check every element of tempArray.

Is there a way to implement Ruby's `Array.include?` so that I don't need to use a loop?

Comment: Similar Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to search for a value:

```
var includePokhara = ( tempArray.indexOf("Pokhara") >= 0 );
```

Unfortunately, `Array.indexOf` is not implemented in Internet Explorer, but you can look on StackOverflow [how to add it back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-ie-browsers).

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is "indexOf". Thanks for additional info related to IE.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT** - in es6 you can just use [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):
`'Blue Whale'.includes('blue'); // returns false`

You can also use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) for that, which has more elegant way to write it:

```
$.inArray(value, array)
```