# unique attribute values with jquery

Tags: jquery

is there a way to get all the unique values for a certain attribute.

e.g

```
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="dog"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="cat"></div>
<div class="bob" data-xyz="fish"></div>
```

I need to get all the distinct values for data-xyz attribute on div.bob,

so it should return fish, dog and cat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Small code: Create an object and make 'dog' 'fish' 'cat' properties. That will make them unique. Then get the unique property names from the object. Simple and easy:

```
var items = {};
$('div.bob').each(function() {
    items[$(this).attr('data-xyz')] = true; 
});

var result = new Array();
for(var i in items)
{
    result.push(i);
}
alert(result);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GxxLj/1/

Answer (score 3):

Keep track of which values you have already processed:

```
var seen = {};

var values = $('div.bob').map(function() {
    var value = this.getAttribute('data-xyz');
    // or $(this).attr('data-xyz');
    // or $(this).data('xyz');

    if(seen.hasOwnProperty(value)) return null;

    seen[value] = true;
    return value;
}).get();
```

**Reference:** [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

This, of course, only works with primitive values. In case you are mapping to objects, you'd have to override the `toString()` method of the objects so that they can be used as keys.

Or as plugin:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.map_unique = function(callback) {
        var seen = {};
        function cb() {
            var value = callback.apply(this, arguments);
            if(value === null || seen.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
                return null;
            }
            seen[value] = true;
            return value;
        }
        return this.map(cb);
    });

}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = $('div.bob').map(function() { return $(this).data('xyz'); });
```

That will return all values. Then you can run it through a unique function.

[How do I make an array with unique elements (i.e. remove duplicates)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940103/how-do-i-make-unique-array/6940176#6940176)

```
function ArrNoDupe(a) {
    var temp = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        temp[a[i]] = true;
    var r = [];
    for (var k in temp)
        r.push(k);
    return r;
}
array = ArrNoDupe(array);
```