# how to get index of a string from a list?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list like

```
_Value1 = "'apple','ball','cat'....so on";
```

If I know that apple exists in above list.How to get index of whole string from the list.Like apple should have the index 1, ball should have 2 and so on.

What is the javascript code for this stuff?

Comment: Just loop through it doing a comparison, once found check your value of i

Answer (score 4):

```
var _Value1 = "'apple','ball','cat'";

// split the string on ","
var values = _Value1.split(",");

// call the indexOf method
var index = values.indexOf("'apple'");
```

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Yt5fp/

---

You can also do this check if it is an older browser and add the `indexOf` method if it doesn't exist

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf)
{
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/) {
        var len = this.length;
        var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
        from = (from < 0) ? Math.ceil(from) : Math.floor(from);
        if (from < 0) from += len;
        for (; from < len; from++) {
            if (from in this && this[from] === elt) return from;
        }
        return -1;
    };
}
```

Comment: Is `indexOf()`supported in all browsers?

Comment: supported by all major browsers

Answer (score 0):

Try using this trick:

```
_Array = eval("[" + _Value1 + "]");
```

(It will create object of array using JSON)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your strings (apple, ball, cat...) will not have a `,` in them:

You can [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) a string based on a delimiter:

```
var split = _values.split(",")
```

You will get an array of strings: `{'apple', 'ball', 'cat'}`

You can use the [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method in the array to find the position of an element:

```
split.indexOf('apple')
```

`indexOf` is not supported by IE. You can use the alternative in [How to fix Array indexOf() in JavaScript for Internet Explorer browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-ie-browsers)