# Custom js/jQuery code is generating error only on IE7 & IE8: Object does not support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have custom js/jquery code which is running fine on all browsers including IE9 except IE8 and IE 7. It says: Object does not support this property or method. http://screencast.com/t/YJkW5NF2gg

The code starts from the line, error refers to, is look like:

```
if(myBrand.indexOf(item) > -1){
    $("ul.brandList", self.checkboxContainer).append(p);
}else if(myPro.indexOf(item) > -1){
    $("ul.proList", self.checkboxContainer).append(p);
}else if(mySize.indexOf(item) > -1){
    $("ul.sizeList", self.checkboxContainer).append(p);
}else if(myColor.indexOf(item) > -1){
            $("ul.colorList", self.checkboxContainer).append(p);
}
```

Any Idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Which line is the one throwing the error?

Comment: It is very first line of the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, IE just doesn't know that method. As the error says... (And google tells you, too!)

You'd either have to create a jQuery object out of the array or define the function to the array prototype yourself, see [here](http://soledadpenades.com/2007/05/17/arrayindexof-in-internet-explorer/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-ie-browsers)