# How to compare two arrays for identical objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, comparison

### Background

Let's say I have two arrays of objects. Each object in each array should be unique, but sometimes we have the same object in both arrays!

```
Array 1: [{fruit: "banana"}, {fruit: "orange"}]
Array 2: [{fruit: "apple"}, {fruit: "banana"}, {fruit: "strawberry"}]
```

Each array has a random number of objects, as you can see.

### Objective

Imagine I have a function called `isSameObj(obj1, obj2)` that returns true or false depending if `ob1 === ob2` or not.

Using this function, I want to know if Array1 has an object repeated in Array2 and vice-versa.

To achieve this, I first started with the traditional for loop.

```
//assuming Array1.length > Array2.length
for(const obj1 of Array1){
    for(const obj2 of Array2){
        if(isSameObj(obj1, obj2)){
            //do some work
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the imperative way most of us are used to.

### Problem

However, recently I tried functional programming. And I find it incredibly hard to implement this small example functionally!

The closest I got to success was using `map`, but `map` always traverses the entire array no matter what and I want to stop and break the loop once I find a repeated object.

Some gentlemen suggest to just `throw` inside the map, but that really is a solution I would rather avoid. I want to break a loop, not signal an error.

### Question

How would I implement this code snippet functionally?

Comment: So, what exactly is _"this code"_ supposed to do now? Return `true/false` depending on if there's an item that exists in both arrays?

Comment: The object here is to have a function that given two arrays, can detect if they share an object and return that object. Otherwise, return undefined :D

Comment: Just use (tail) recursion. Btw, _Otherwise, return undefined_ - this isn't a good idea. In FP functions always return something, no matter how many cases they deal with.

Comment: @Cerbrus Jesus, have you even read my question? You just marked it as a duplicate when it is STATED that type of solution IS NOT WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR. I guess I should have put it in bold....

Comment: @ftor I guess that's an idea worth exploring !

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: Please calm down. Look at the 2nd answer there. The accepted answer isn't great, but the other answer _does_ meet your requirements. The `filter` / `some` combination is as short / fast as it'll get without manual `for` loops you'd break out of.

Comment: @Cerbrus It does not meet the requirements because the answer uses filter, which traverses the entire array, even after a duplicate is found. This is exactly what I am trying to avoid :D

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix I posted a new answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46770626/3211932), it satisfies your initial goal. Just do a combination of two finds: `const checkFirst = (a1, a2) => !!a2.find(i1 => a1.find(i2 => i2.fruit === i1.fruit));`

Comment: Okay, there are no "iterate over array" functions that both short-circuits (`some/any`), __and__ return array entries (`map/filter`). If you want to short-circuit at the _first_ match, your best bet is a loop with a `some` in it.

Comment: @dhilt: Note that [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility) isn't supported by IE

Comment: @Cerbrus So, let's use `some`...

Comment: @dhilt: `some` doesn't return array entries. That outer `find` would have to be replaced with a `for` loop.

Comment: @Cerbrus But here it would be enough, I guess. The author wants true/false at the end.

Comment: So: `const checkFirst = (a1, a2) => a2.some(i1 => a1.some(i2 => i2.fruit === i1.fruit));`

Comment: _"detect if they share an object **and return that object.**"_ (First comment by OP here)

Comment: Damn... `const findFirst = (a1, a2) => { let result; a2.some(i1 => a1.some(i2 => i2.fruit === i1.fruit ? result = i1 : false )); return result; }`

Comment: That would work, but then I'd be wondering why someone is (ab)using `some` instead of a `for` loop you can simply `return` out of...

Comment: @Cerbrus I agree with you!

Comment: Returning true/false is not he idea here, the idea, as stated before, would be to have it return the object, or undefined if nothing. I will have a look at your new answer, although I have to wonder why you posted it there instead of here, since in the other question no one is asking for a short-circuit.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix This question is closed for answers, unfortunately. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770250/how-to-compare-two-arrays-for-identical-objects?noredirect=1#comment80487101_46770250) try if you don't want `.find()`.

Comment: It is closed because @Cerbrus wrongly classified it as a duplicate and forced you to post the answer in another question, thus depriving me of the opportunity to properly thank you by accepting your answer... At least I upvoted your answer in the other thread.

Comment: I also added a link to this post. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is literally the same. The short-circuit requirement isn't really a significant difference.

Comment: Not if you have a machine with infinity memory. Who are you to say what is and what is not a significant difference? I am the OP, and I made it clear that this was a significant difference for me. *I did that twice*. You made a mistake in classifying this as a duplicate and now your ego is simply justifying the unjustifiable. If you were to start a conversation with me and wrongly deduce such conclusion, I could understand it, but you didn't even do that. You just put my question into the DUP bag and then didn't allow me nor anyone else to confront your decision.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: if you wish to contest a duplicate classification, you can post on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Keep it calm and level-headed, and realise that either of you may have made a wrong assessment, and you'll be fine.