# javascript check existence of elements of 1 array inside the other

Tags: javascript, arrays

For searching elements of one array inside the other, one may use the indexOf() on the target of search and run a loop on the other array elements and in each step check existence. This is trivial and my knowledge on Javascript is too. Could any one please suggest a more efficient way? Maybe even a built-in method of the language could help? Although I couldn't hit to such a method using google.

Comment: `indexOf` is probably as efficient as you need, but there are some other methods mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript and possibly at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076067/finding-matches-between-multiple-javascript-arrays

Comment: You have to use `indexOf` or a loop for a reliable cross browser solution. There are methods available in frameworks like jQuery (e.g: `inArray`), but that also make use of the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** internally and implement a function on Array's prototype which returns elements which are common to both.

```js
Array.prototype.common = function(a) {
    return this.filter(function(i) {
      return a.indexOf(i) >= 0;
    });
};


alert([1,2,3,4,5].common([4,5,6])); // "4, 5"
```

Again as you mention in your post, this logic also works by taking each element and checking whether it exists in the other.

Answer (score 1):

A hair more efficient way is convert one of the arrays into a hash table and then loop through the second one, checking the presence of elements at O(1) time:

```js
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,7,3,8,5]

map = {}
a.forEach(function(x) { map[x] = 1 })
intersection = b.filter(function(x) { return map[x] === 1 })

document.write(JSON.stringify(intersection))
```

This only works if elements in question are primitives. For arrays of objects you have to resort to the `indexOf` method.

ES6 ("Harmony") does support [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), but strangely not set operations (union, intersection etc), so these should be coded by hand:

```js
// Firefox only

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,7,3,8,5]

sa = new Set(a)
sb = new Set(b)

sa.forEach(function(x) {
  if (!sb.has(x))
    sa.delete(x);
});

document.write(uneval([...sa]))
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript's arrays don't have a method that does intersections. Various libraries provide methods to do it (by looping the array as you describe), including [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection) and [PrototypeJS](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Array/prototype/intersect/) (and others, I'm sure).