# How to find common elements of n arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array (let's call it *masterArray*) that contains *n* inner arrays (number of arrays can be infinite): innerArray1, innerArray2, innerArray3. How to get common elements of all arrays? By common elements I mean elements that exists in every inner array.

Below is my array structure:

```
masterArray = [
    innerArray1 = [
        element1,
        element2,
        element5,
        element6,
        element8
    ],
    innerArray2 = [
        element1,
        element2,
        element4,
        element5,
        element10
    ],
    innerArray3 = [
        element2,
        element1,
        element5,
        element3,
        element10
    ]
]
```

So common elements of these three inner arrays would be only: element1, element2 and element5.

Comment: @blgt not really, in my case there's more than 2 arrays (infinite number of arrays) and they are not sorted actually.

Comment: "number of arrays can be infinite" – It most certainly cannot. Mabye you mean arbitrary, but surely not infinite.

Comment: @PawełLudwiczak Your case is different in the same way multiplication is different to addition. Just stick it in a loop and you're done.

Comment: There's actually answer for what I've been looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076067/finding-matches-between-multiple-javascript-arrays
My question can be closed.