# Check if an array o html elements have some of the following classes

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, comparison

```
// HTML
```

// Some Html content

```
<div class=​"class--1 common-class otherClass2">​…​</div>​

// Some Html content
<div class="otherdiv"></div>

<div class=​"common-class class--2">​…​</div>​
<div class=​"common-class class--3 otherClass">​…​</div>​

// Some Html content
```

i'm trying to iterate between 2 arrays;
one with className stored and the other with html elements targeted

```
// JAVASCRIPT 
var arrayOfClasses  = ["class--5", "class--10", "class--1", "class--2"];

    var arrayOfElements = document.getElementsByClassName("common-class");
    // This return the following array
    // [<div class=​"common-class class--1">​…​</div>​, <div class=​"common-class class--2>​…​</div>​, <div class=​"common-class class--3>​…​</div>​];
```

How i get **true** value for the element with *class--1* and *class--2* and **false** for *class--3* *class--5* and *class--10*

I iterate throw the `arrayOfElements[i].className`
and after use the indexOf commented below
but found another problem here :S

```
"common-class class--10".indexOf("class--1")
// Return > 13     but  i want -1 because is 10 no 1
```

Better without jQuery
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076067/finding-matches-between-multiple-javascript-arrays

Comment: `.forEach` and `.indexOf` should do it.

Comment: @gurvinder372 thanks ! i searched in the answers but didn't find that

But that just return the coincidences, how i got false for the other values ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array1 = ["Hello", 5, "Hola", 27, 'otherValue'];
var array2 = [27, "Hello"];

var intersection = [];

var intersectionObj = {};

for(var i=0; i<array1.length; i++) {
  if(array2.indexOf(array1[i]) > -1) {
    intersection.push(array1[i]);
  }
}
alert(intersection);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
</body>
</html>
```