# I have multiple arrays and I want to know if any of the two arrays have at least one element in common in js or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, unique

I have arrays like 
`["key1",key2","key3"],["key4","key5","key6"],["key1","key7",key8","key9"]`
In this "`key1`" is common in first and third array.I want to identify this scenario.

EDIT This question is not a duplicate of [Finding matches between multiple JavaScript Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076067/finding-matches-between-multiple-javascript-arrays).

I don't want to find the common elements of multiple arrays. I want to check whether atleast two arrays(any two) have atleast one common element.(This element need not be in other arrays in the set).

And I found the answer as well,Assume there won't be same elements inside an array.

Ans:

```
    var containerKeys=[];
    for(var i = 0;i < arraySet.length; i++ )
    {
        var arrValues = arraySet[i].value;
        var keys = arrValues.split(",");

        //checking whether different arrays have same keyword
        var intersection=containerKeys.filter(function(n) {
           return keys.indexOf(n) != -1;});
        if(intersection.length>0){
        //Show error that there are same elements.
           return false;}
        containerKeys=containerKeys.concat(keys);
    }
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: Another dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript (note that the second answer is the best one)