# Return only elements containing specific characters

Tags: javascript

I need to check each element of an array for a certain letter. if the element contains this letter it should stay within the array, if it does not it should be removed.

currently I'm able to remove elements if they are exact, but not sure how to go about checking each index of each element.

```
var exampleList = ['alpha', 'beta','dog']

exampleList.filter(function(word) {
    return (word == 'dog');
})
```

my end goal would be something like this.

```
letterToInclude = 'a'
var exampleList = ['alpha', 'beta','dog', 'mouse']

exampleList.filter(function(word) {
    return (word == letterToInclude);
})
// returned values = ['alpha', 'beta']
```

Comment: `list.filter(word => word.includes(letter))`

Comment: i like `['alpha','beta','dog'].filter(/./.test, RegExp( "a"  ));`, but you can write out the functions manually if desired; a lot of people don't understand generic recycling...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of doing `==`, you can use `indexOf` to see if `letterToInclude` occurs in `word`.

```
letterToInclude = 'a'
var exampleList = ['alpha', 'beta','dog', 'mouse']

exampleList.filter(function(word) {
    return (word.indexOf(letterToInclude) > -1);
});
```

`indexOf` returns the position that `letterToInclude` occurs in `word`; in the event it is not found, `indexOf` will return `-1`.

The reason I didn't use `word.includes(letterToInclude)` is just for compatibility purposes. `includes` is fairly new and [isn't completely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

Comment: thanks for the help, I must have been using indexOf wrong prior to this.

Comment: Would comparing an array of words to include be similar to this?

Comment: A good answer to that question could be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076067/finding-matches-between-multiple-javascript-arrays

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf()` to check if each element contains a specific letter.

```js
var letterToInclude = 'a'
var exampleList = ['alpha', 'beta', 'dog', 'mouse']

exampleList = exampleList.filter(function(word) {
  return word.indexOf(letterToInclude) != -1
})

console.log(exampleList)
```

ES6 solution with `String#includes()`, also you can use `match()` or `test()` but those take regular expressions.

```
exampleList.filter(word => word.includes(letterToInclude))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```js
letterToInclude = 'a'
var exampleList = ['alpha', 'beta','dog', 'mouse']

console.log(exampleList.filter(function(word) {
    return ~(word.indexOf(letterToInclude));
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

It works well together with Unicode chars:

```js
var lettersToInclude = 'aa'
var exampleList = ['a', 'aa','❤✓☀a★bAb', 'bbaa', 'aa☂']

var r = exampleList.filter(function(word) {
    return (word.indexOf(lettersToInclude) > -1);
});

console.log(r);
```