# How to get all items that are both is array A and B and save them in array C? using javascript without using loops

Tags: javascript, arrays

lets say I have

```
var A = [x, y, z]
var B = [1, 2, z, 3, x]
```

How can I get items present both in A and B like so

```
var C = [AB]
```

Without having to loop through both arrays to check for each iteration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)

Comment: @H77 OP wants union. Not intersection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding matches between multiple JavaScript Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076067/finding-matches-between-multiple-javascript-arrays)

Comment: @SureshAtta he says _items present both in A and B_.  I assume that means intersection. But his example `C = [AB]` implies that it is union.

Comment: What is expected result of `C`?

Comment: C should be the interception

Comment: But I don't want to use the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript because they use a loop and am worried about execution time

Comment: Is expected result of `C` `[x, y, z, 1, 2, z, 3, x]` or `[x, y, z, 1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: @KamgaSimoJunior you mean *intersection*. You can't know what are in the 2 arrays unless you iterate through both of them.

Comment: C should give [x, z] for the above example

Comment: I think in php we use something like array_diff() to do the opposite without using any loop

Comment: Internally it will be iterating through.

Comment: yes but i think it will be more faster than doing that manually

Comment: Is requirement to not use `Array.prototype` methods?

Comment: `Array.prototype` to do what?

Comment: To get expected result

Comment: can please post an answer to be more explicit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()` and `Array.prototype.includes()` to determine if both arrays contain the same element, `Set` to remove duplicate elements from resulting array

```js
var A = ["x", "y", "z"]
var B = [1, 2, "z", 3, "x"]
var C = [...new Set(
          [...A, ...B].filter(prop => A.includes(prop) && B.includes(prop)))
        ];

console.log(C);
```

Answer (score 1):

With duplicates:

```
var C = [...A, ...B]
// Result: C = ["x", "y", "z", 1, 2, "z", 3, "x"]
```

Without duplicates:

```
var C = [...A, ...B].filter((el, i, a) => i === a.indexOf(el))
// Result: C = ["x", "y", "z", 1, 2, 3]
```

**Update:** if you want the intersection of both arrays:

```
var C = A.filter(function(n) {
    return B.indexOf(n) !== -1;
});
// Result: C = ["x", "z"]
```

Comment: what will be the value of C

Comment: in the first example: `["x", "y", "z", 1, 2, "z", 3, "x"]` and in the second one `["x", "y", "z", 1, 2, 3]`

Comment: i want C to be `[x, z]` the intersect

Comment: a.indexOf is still a linear search -> you're just calling a convenience method for a loop that loops through the entire array until it finds a match or it's looped through every item in the array without a match.

Comment: then you should use ```A.filter(function(n) {
    return B.indexOf(n) !== -1;
});```

Comment: You are still looping! for every item in a, you are looping through either every element in B (for indexOf = -1) or until you find a match in B. calling indexOf === doing a loop. You still loop through B multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let a = new Set(["x", "y", "z"]);
let b = new Set([1, 2, "z", 3, "x"]);

let intersection = [...a].filter(x => b.has(x));
console.log(intersection);
```

Answer (score -2):

Sort each array then merge?

```
/* sort DESC */
A.sort(function(a,b){ return b-a; })
B.sort(function(a,b){ return b-a; })
```

then use:

```
function union_destructive(a, b)
{
  var result = [];
  while( a.length > 0 || b.length > 0 )
  {  
     if      (a[0] > b[0] ){ result.push(a.shift()); }
     else if (a[0] < b[0] ){ result.push(b.shift()); }
     else /* they're equal */
     {
       result.push(a.shift());
       b.shift();
     }
  }

  return result;
}
```

([Simplest code for array intersection in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)):

Thats O(n log n).

Comment: I don't want to use a loop am worry about the execution time

Comment: @KamgaSimoJunior You want matched elements or you want to mix both of them with unique elements?

Comment: please check the comments above

Comment: after the sort - which is an efficient implementation, you loop AT MOST a.length + b.length times - you never loop over the same item twice.