# How to determine if two strings contain the same word in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6, exif

So, I'm mostly interested in seeing who has a clever solution to this problem. It's likely going to come down to `split` and some comparison loop.

**The problem:** I am combining multiple fields of exif data to create a title for an image. The trouble is that this exif data ranges widely in content.

Nikon example:

```
exifData.Make = "NIKON CORPORATION"
exifData.Model = "NIKON D90"
```

Motorola phone example:

```
exifData.Make = "Motorola"
exifData.Model = "XT1032"
```

In the Motorola case, I'd simply use the combination of `Make` and `Model`.

However, in the Nikon case, there's duplication, so I'd like to ignore the `Make` and give preference to the `Model` in that case.

Comment: If you use `split` then you can compute the intersection of the two arrays you'll get (https://stackoverflow.com/q/11076067/3410584). Then, if the intersection is not empty, you'll have to implement your own logic to know what field you prefer.

Comment: @ValLeNain As far as I can see that doesn't handle case insensitivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `Make` into a RegExp that contains a group of words, and [test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) if the `Model` contains a match. If it contains, take the `Model`, if not, combine `Make` and `Model`.

```js
const getTitle = ({ Make, Model }) =>
  new RegExp('\\b' + Make.replace(/\s+/g, '|') + '\\b', 'i')
    .test(Model) ? Model : `${Make} ${Model}`;

console.log(getTitle({ Make: "Motorola", Model: "XT1032" }));
console.log(getTitle({ Make: "NIKON CORPORATION", Model: "NIKON D90" }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the `Make` string and check first token within `Model` using `includes()`:

```js
let exifData1 = {Make: "NIKON CORPORATION", Model: "NIKON D90"},
    exifData2 = {Make: "Motorola", Model: "XT1032"};

function getName(o) {
  return !o.Model.includes(o.Make.split(" ")[0]) ? o.Make + " " + o.Model : o.Model;
}

console.log(getName(exifData1));
console.log(getName(exifData2));
```

Comment: It should print `NIKON D90` the model has higher priority.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande Sorry, Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let exifData = {};

exifData.Make = "NIKON CORPORATION"
exifData.Model = "NIKON D90"

let elems = {},
  repeats = {};

let make = exifData.Make.toLowerCase().split(" ").forEach(data => {
  elems[data] = true;
});

let model = exifData.Model.toLowerCase().split(" ").forEach(data => {
  if(elems[data]) repeats[data] = true;
});
```