# Comparing JSON arrays to return matches

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

Is it possible to return matching values by comparing JSON arrays. For example;

```
0 : ['cat1', 'cat2']
1 : ['cat2', 'cat3']
2 : ['cat2', 'cat4']
```

The above should return `'cat2'` as that exists in all 3 arrays.

EDIT: I found this snippet ([Finding matches between multiple JavaScript Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076067/finding-matches-between-multiple-javascript-arrays)) which appears to do the first part;

```
var result = obj.shift().filter(function(v) {
  return obj.every(function(a) {
    return a.indexOf(v) !== -1;
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

However, if an array is added that has no matches, this should return `false` and no results;

```
0 : ['cat1', 'cat2']
1 : ['cat2', 'cat3']
2 : ['cat2', 'cat4']
3 : ['cat5']
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = obj.shift().filter(function(v) {
  return obj.every(function(a) {
    return a.indexOf(v) !== -1;
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Is actually the answer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do that using python code, here's an example:

```py
array_list = [
    ['cat1', 'cat2'],
    ['cat2', 'cat3'],
    ['cat2', 'cat4']
]


def find_common_words(array_list):
    if len(array_list) == 0:
        return []

    common_words = set(array_list[0])
    for array in array_list[1:]:
        common_words = common_words.intersection(array)
    return list(common_words)


print(find_common_words(array_list))
```