# indexOf is not a function in Firefox, Opera but works in IE, indexOf alternative in javascript to test string contains?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, testing, indexof

Getting an error using indexOf call in Javascript on Firefox and Opera.  Works fine in IE.

Following is the error message:

Action

```
function anonymous(Grid, Row, Col, Event) { 
    return Grid.ActionShowPopupMenu(); 
}
```

for event OnRightClick failed with exception: row.id.indexOf is not a function

I'm testing that a string contains another string in Javascript and using the indexOf function of a string.  The calls however are being made in JQuery functions.  Perhaps that is the reason for the problem?  Is there an alternative to using indexOf in Javascript to test if a string contains another string?  Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: indexOf definitely works in FF. Been using it for not sure how long.. It might be a problem is with the object you're calling it with.

Comment: If you're passing jQuery objects, especially if `Row` is a jQ object, `.id` will be undefined/null. Either use `Row.getAttr('id').indexOf()` or use `Row.get(0).id.indexOf()`. If that fails, too: `Row` is capitalized in your function declaration, but the exception shows a lower case `row`. JS is CaseSensitive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String.indexOf is perfectly OK in all browsers. I assume the *id* property of your *row* object is no string (nor array, btw, because indexOf is also defined on arrays (except for IE))

Comment: yes, that was the problem.  id was not always a string.  thanks for all the comments!

Answer (score 3):

indexOf is not okay for IE prior to IE9. If you want your code to work in ie < 9, you should define the method for non-compliant browsers in a common js file that can be dropped into every page. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-ie-browsers) for more details. The code is taken from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement /*, fromIndex */ ) {
        "use strict";
        if (this == null) {
            throw new TypeError();
        }
        var t = Object(this);
        var len = t.length >>> 0;
        if (len === 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        var n = 0;
        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            n = Number(arguments[1]);
            if (n != n) { // shortcut for verifying if it's NaN
                n = 0;
            } else if (n != 0 && n != Infinity && n != -Infinity) {
                n = (n > 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(n));
            }
        }
        if (n >= len) {
            return -1;
        }
        var k = n >= 0 ? n : Math.max(len - Math.abs(n), 0);
        for (; k < len; k++) {
            if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement) {
                return k;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

indexOf() is ok for all browsers. It is designed for both, String and Array, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/SquTp/

There is maybe something wrong with your dom selection, or you may use it in the wrong way.