# I am trying to create pie chart using highcharts in SharePoint 2010 Visual Web Part.Not working with default document model of IE 11

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, sharepoint, highcharts

This link has the code: http://jsfiddle.net/agc0fuyk/18/

works fine when :

> Run in jsfiddle (chrome as well as IE 11.0.96).
>
> Run in visual studio asp.net html page (chrome as well as IE 11.0.96).

fails when :

> Run in SharePoint 2010 Visual Web Part(visual studio 2010)

now when I open F12 Developer tool's emulation tab for this IE window, Document mode is set to 5 by default, When I change the document mode to 10, I can see the page/chart loaded properly.

At sharepoint page I have added the meta tag :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

also added JavaScript to remove indexOf error in IE 
Reference from 
[indexOf is not a function in Firefox, Opera but works in IE, indexOf alternative in javascript to test string contains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992766/indexof-is-not-a-function-in-firefox-opera-but-works-in-ie-indexof-alternative)

Please help me to run this in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution to this problem by adding following lines in "Page_Load" of Web-Part:

```
HtmlMeta metaEdgeIE = new HtmlMeta();
metaEdgeIE.HttpEquiv = "X-UA-Compatible";
metaEdgeIE.Content = "IE=EDGE";
Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(0, metaEdgeIE);
```

Now its working well in IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a doctype issue.

Force IE10 standards mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Try to insert that at the top your HTML.

[More info on document compatibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx)