# Javascript array indexOf returns undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, indexof

When calling my function `checkIss()`, `issFullArray.indexOf(issToCheck)` always returns `undefined`.  I've run a `.length`, output the contents of `issFullArray`, I can't figure out why it's not working- the array looks fine to me.  As you can see below, I've tried explicitly setting `issArray` as an array and copying the array returned by my `getIssList()`

```
function updateIss() {
    var issArray = [];

    var currService = current.u_business_service;
    var currIss = current.u_is_service;
    issArray = getIssList(currService).slice(); //getIssList() returns an arry
    if (checkIss(issArray, currIss) === false) {
        //do stuff
    }
}

function checkIss(issFullArray, issToCheck) {
    if (issFullArray.indexOf(issToCheck) < 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a browser that supports array.indexOf.

Comment: IE <=8, for example, doesn't support `indexOf()` for Arrays.

Comment: I've tried IE9, Firefox 15 and Chrome 24.  Are there actually browsers that wouldn't support indexOf()?  Bit silly if you ask me...

Comment: make the scope of issArray global and do not pass it to your checkIss() function and see whether it works

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but it appears it's the software that I'm coding for that doesn't support indexOf.  I find it a bit odd that such a simple function isn't supported but heyho, I'll raise a bug and see what happens!

Comment: IE8 do not support array.indexOf.
so try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-internet-explorer-browsers/29003069#29003069

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest to just loop through the array and compare each value and return true if there is a match otherwise return false. Not much more code and works for all browsers.

```
function checkIss(issFullArray, issToCheck) {
    for(i=0; i<issFullArray.length; i++) {
        if(issFullArray[i]==issToCheck) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ElPedro, it looks like I'll ne using this!