# Sort array using another array in Javascript in IE8

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, internet-explorer-8

I have got an array like this:

```
[1, Stopped]
[2, Waiting]
[3, Finished]
[4, Stopped]
[5, Running]
```

The number is the id of the program and the text is the status of the program. I need to sort this array according to the next order:

```
['Error','Halted','Blocked','Finished','Waiting to Start','Waiting','Stopping','Running','Idle','Stopped','Opened','Ready'];
```

I use this for every other browser except IE8:

```
var a = [[1, 'Stopped'],
[2, 'Waiting'],
[3, 'Finished'],
[4, 'Stopped'],
[5, 'Running']];
var order = ['Error','Halted','Blocked','Finished','Waiting to Start','Waiting','Stopping','Running','Idle','Stopped','Opened','Ready'];

a.sort(function (a, b) {
   return order.indexOf(a[1]) - order.indexOf(b[1]);
});
```

It is working in all different browsers except for IE8. Can anyone tell me how to sort it in IE8?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it IE developer tools?

Comment: Have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-ie-browsers. Have you implemented a workaround for the indexOf functionality? `array.indexOf()` is not supported in IE8

Comment: In particular, you need to use what is called a "polyfill" to patch in the missing functionality. Here is one you can copy/paste: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility

Comment: I looked at tha, but I have no idea how to implement that into my code. Every time I try to implement it, all browsers stop working.

Comment: @user1350637: Then you are making some type of elementary syntax error. Look at the console of a developer-friendly browser for error messages.

Comment: Ok, just to be certain. I need to paste the code mentioned in the mozilla page at the beginning of my .js file? Or just in the beginning of the function I used it in?

Answer (score 2):

IE8 does not support `array.indexOf()`. You'll need to find an alternative.

Possible solutions:

1. Use jQuery (or a similar library), which gives [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) as a direct replacement for `array.indexOf()`.
2. Use a polyfill library that adds a replacement `.indexOf` method to the Array prototype. [Here's one possible option](https://github.com/petermichaux/polyfill). (others available via google of course)
3. Rewrite your code to search through the array using a simple loop.