# How to remove array elements in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays like this,

```
arr1 = ['20', 'annL', 'annT', '25', 'annL', 'annT', '44', 'annL', 'annT']

arr2 = ['2013-11-29','50','annL','annT', '20','annL','annT', '25','annL','annT', '44','annL','annT', '96','annL','annT', '26','annL','annT', '10','annL','annT']
```

I want to remove arr1 elements from arr2.

I have used,

```
array.splice()
```

but couldn't able to solve the problem

Please help me,

Thank You.

Comment: Implement a relative complement set operation...

Comment: if you are in a hurry there are loads of great utility libraries like lodash and underscore that provide functionality like array#diff: http://lodash.com/docs#difference

Answer (score 3):

**Use a Filter**

```
Array.prototype.difference = function(arr) {
    return this.filter(function(i) {return (arr.indexOf(i) == -1);});
}
```

**Usage**

```
arr2.difference(arr1);

[1,2,3,4].difference([1,2])
// => [3,4]
```

**Sidenote**

I think it looks pretty in coffee script aswell:

```
 Array::difference = (arr) ->
   @filter (i) ->
     arr.indexOf(i) is -1
```

Comment: Nice indeed. Note that unlike "hash" solutions this works with any type (i.e. arrays of objects).

Comment: Great let me know :) if there's anything that needs clarification just say

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
for (var i in arr1) {
    var elemPos = arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]);
    while (-1 !== elemPos) {
        arr2.splice(elemPos, 1);
        elemPos = arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: `indexOf` on arrays were first added in IE9+. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-ie-browsers) for compatibility methods.

Answer (score 0):

The following `difference` function if from this library: [array.sets.js](http://code.google.com/p/javascriptsets/source/browse/array.sets.js)

This library provides 6 of the basic set operations.

```
Array.prototype.difference = function(a) {
        var temp = [];
        var keys = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                keys[this[i]] = 1;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                if (keys[a[i]] != undefined) {
                        keys[a[i]] = 2;
                }
        }
        for (var key in keys) {
                if (keys[key] == 1) {
                        temp.push(key);
                }
        }
        return temp;
};

arr1 = ['20', 'annL', 'annT', '25', 'annL', 'annT', '44', 'annL', 'annT'];

arr2 = ['2013-11-29','50','annL','annT', '20','annL','annT', '25','annL','annT', '44','annL','annT', '96','annL','annT', '26','annL','annT', '10','annL','annT'];

console.log(arr2.difference(arr1));
```

Output:

```
["2013-11-29", "50", "96", "26", "10"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
arr1.forEach(
     function(item){ 
         var itemIndex = arr2.indexOf(item);
         if(itemIndex>=0)
           arr2.splice(itemIndex,1);
     }
);
```

**About your commentary**

If arr2 ist a mixed array which value is:

```
var arr2 = [['2013-11-29','50','annL','annT'], ['20','annL','annT', '25','annL'],
'annT', '44','annL','annT', '96','annL','annT', '26','annL','annT', '10','annL','annT'];
```

Passing the algorithm arr2 value will be:

```
[['2013-11-29','50','annL','annT'], ['20','annL','annT', '25','annL'],
 "96", "26", "annT", "10", "annL", "annT"]
```

If what you want is to remove the occurrences of arr1 elements in each arr2 2d array value:

```
var arr2 = [['2013-11-29','50','annL','annT'], ['20','annL','annT', '25','annL'],
['annT', '44','annL','annT', '96','annL','annT'], ['26','annL','annT', '10','annL','annT']];

arr2.forEach(
    function(arrayItem){ 
        arr1.forEach(function(item){ 
            if(arrayItem.indexOf(item)>=0)
                arrayItem.splice(arrayItem.indexOf(item),1);
        });
    });

//arr2 will produce: [['2013-11-29','50'], [], ['96'], ['26','10']]
```

Beware it will produce an error if arr2 isn't a truly 2d array.

Comment: yeah, you can use it but I don't know if the results would be the appropriate. I've updated my answer with this question.