# Javascript: compare variable against array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays

In javascript I am doing the following which works fine.

```
if (myVar == 25 || myVar == 26 || myVar == 27 || myVar == 28)
 {
   //do something
 }
```

How can I shorten it? something like the following.

```
if (myVar IN ('25','26','27','28')) {
    //do something
   }
```

or

```
if(myVar.indexOf("25","26","27","28") > -1) ) {//do something}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), it returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or `-1` if it is not present.

*Use*

```js
var arr = [25, 26, 27, 28];
console.log(arr.indexOf(25) > -1);
console.log(arr.indexOf(31) > -1);
```

---

[Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method can also be used it returns `boolean`.

```js
var arr = [25, 26, 27, 28];
console.log(arr.includes(25));
console.log(arr.includes(31));
```

Answer (score 9):

Just try with:

```
if ( [25, 26, 27, 28].indexOf(myVar) > -1 ) {}
```

Comment: For compatibility see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-internet-explorer-browsers

Comment: As indicated in that thread, if you're using jQuery, you can use `$.inArray(

Answer (score 3):

Other way :

```
myVar = (myVar == parseInt(myVar) ? myVar : false); //to check if variable is an integer and not float
if ( myVar >= 25 && myVar <= 28){}
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tQRPt/)

**Edit** *based on the comment of Anthony Grist*

This way works if you know what those values are going to be (i.e. they're not dynamic) and your array contains a series of consecutive numeric values.

Comment: `> 24 && < 29` is even shorter :)

Comment: Fine if you know what those values are going to be (i.e. they're not dynamic) and your array contains a series of consecutive numeric values.

Answer (score 3):

Since `indexOf()`, has some browser compatibility issues and requires an extra step (of comparing the result to -1), an alternative, cross-browser approach is the following jQuery utility method (if you include jQuery in your project) :

```
if($.inArray(myVar, [25, 26, 27, 28]) > -1) {
     // ... do something ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> if ( [25, 26, 27, 28].indexOf(myVar) > -1 ) {}

Array.indexOf will work fine for all modern browsers(FF, Chrome, >IE8), just a word of caution is that Array.indexOf will not work for IE8.
If you want to make it work in IE8 please use the below code:

> window.onload = function() {
>
> if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
>
> > ```
> > Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/) {
> >   var len = this.length >>> 0;
> >   var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
> >   from = (from < 0) ? Math.ceil(from) : Math.floor(from);
> >   if (from < 0) {
> >     from += len;
> >   }
> >   for (; from < len; from++) {
> >     if (from in this && this[from] === elt){
> >       return from;
> >   }
> > }
> > return -1;
> > ```
> >
> > };
>
> }
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

```
var validValues = [25, 26, 27, 28]
var myVar = 25

if (validValues.includes(myVar)) {
    //do something
}
```