# Get selected element from cursor/selection in oldIE

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-8, selection

I want to check if the selection or the cursor is in an element or in an element from this element.

I thought I could go through the parent elements of the selected element to check this.
Something like this:

```
var elements = [el_1, el_2, el_3]; // element x, y and z

function elementActiv(el) {
    if (elements.indexOf(el) == -1) {
        if (el.parentElement) {
            return elementActiv(el.parentElement);
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

function check() {
    var selectedElement;

    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        // IE 9 and other non-IE browsers
        selectedElement = window.getSelection().baseNode.parentElement;
    }
    else if (document.selection) {
        // IE 8 and below
        selectedElement = ???; // How to get the selected element here??
    }

    if (selectedElement) {
        return elementActiv(selectedElement);
    }
}
```

My problem is I don't know how to get the selected element in IE 8 and below.
Did somebody know how to do this? *Or did somebody know how to do this with another solution?*

Comment: Stop worrying about IE8 support and move on :)

Comment: There's a project called [Rangy](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) but really, unless you've been told "do it for IE8", don't support obsolete software

Comment: @Matt Ball: I wish I could do that!!! But some customers have still Windows XP and use IE8 ;(

Comment: @rontornambe: jQuery doesn't really help to solve this problem

Comment: No jQuery sorry. Plain JS.

Comment: I get a solution 'document.selection.createRange().parentElement()'. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Solution to get the selected element in IE 8 and below.

```
document.selection.createRange().parentElement()
```

Thanks.

---

Note that you need the indexOf prototype for IE:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
        for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
            if (this[i] === obj) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Idae from here:
[How to fix Array indexOf() in JavaScript for Internet Explorer browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-internet-explorer-browsers)

---

If somebody has a better Idea to solve my problem then go through all parent elements, I would be grateful to hear it.

Comment: Please be aware that this will not always return an ancestor of the whole selection (see [**here**](https://code.google.com/p/rangy/source/browse/tags/1_2/currentrelease/uncompressed/rangy-core.js#1882) )

Comment: @Paul S.: Thanks for the warning and the reference.
If I understand the comment you referenced correct, then this is not a problem, because I go through my loop and the next one (the first parentElement) would be the "right" element, the element with the selection.